# How can I make the date criteria show all records when left blank in the following formula?

Tags: ms-access, search

I have made a search form that allows the user to search within company expense reports for certain clients, projects, employees, and date ranges.

For the Date Criteria Box I have the following formula:

```
Between [Forms]![Search Form]![txtDateFrom] And [Forms]![Search Form]![txtDateTo]
```

This works fine but if I don't input any dates then no records show up, I want to change this so that all records will show up if they are left blank.

I've been able to do this for the project, client, and employee fields with the following formulas:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Search Form]![cboProject] & "*"
Like "*" & [Forms]![Search Form]![cboClient] & "*"
Like "*" & [Forms]![Search Form]![txtEmployee] & "*"
```

You guys probably know exactly what this means but I'll briefly explain it anyways: when I enter something in the textbox for Employee, the combo box for Project, or the combo box for Client in my search for and run the query, only the values that match what I entered appear. The Like "*" bit makes it so that if nothing is entered all the values show up.

I want to do the same for the date range but it is a bit trickier for me to do, can anyone help me with the syntax of this to make my date from and date to boxes show everything if left empty? Because right now if i leave them empty no records are shown which is a **huge** problem for the user side.

I've tried:

```
Like "*" & (Between [Forms]![Search Form]![txtDateFrom] And [Forms]![Search Form]![txtDateTo]) & "*"
```

But it didn't work for me and when I would input date ranges the incorrect date ranges would appear in the query.

What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: I would share a picture of my form and the formulas to give a better sense of what I'm talking about but I'm still relatively new to SO and don't have the requried 10 reputation yet :(

Comment: i can email the pictures if need be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like now your query returns the correct rows when both *txtDateFrom* and *txtDateTo* contain non-Null values.

But you want all rows returned when either *txtDateFrom* or *txtDateTo* is Null.  In that case you can add 2 conditions to your `WHERE` clause:

```sql
WHERE
       your_date_field Between [Forms]![Search Form]![txtDateFrom] And [Forms]![Search Form]![txtDateTo]
    OR [Forms]![Search Form]![txtDateFrom] Is Null
    OR [Forms]![Search Form]![txtDateTo] Is Null
```

Comment: this is really great @HansUp
but will this require sql? or can i type this into my criteria box

Comment: Switch your query from Design View to SQL View.  Add the first Is Null condition in SQL View and then you can switch back to Design View again to see how it is represented there.

Comment: nevermind!! @HansUp
this is amazing! worked like a charm thank you so much. i would upvote your comment but i don't have the reputation for it sadly. when i do i'll be sure to come back to this and give you that upvote!

Comment: i was able to do it in the criteria box after all

Comment: OK.  Still take some time to compare the same changes in Design View and SQL View.  That effort will introduce you to Access SQL syntax ... and that understanding will be invaluable for future Access development.  Cheers.

Comment: how do i include with multiple wheres? Like this

    WHERE ((([Master Expense Sheet].[Employee Name]) Like "*" & Forms![Search Form]!txtEmployee & "*") And (([Master Expense Sheet].Year) Like "*" & Forms![Search Form]!txtYear & "*") And (([Master Expense Sheet].Month) Like "*" & Forms![Search Form]!txtMonth & "*") And (([Master Expense Sheet].Date) Between Forms![Search Form]!txtDateFrom And Forms![Search Form]!txtDateTo) And (([Master Expense Sheet].Client) Like "*" & Forms![Search Form]!cboClient & "*");

Comment: sorry for the messiness

Comment: I can't figure out the logic you're trying to accomplish from that.  As I wild guess, I suspect you may need `OR` in place of `AND` for some of those.  And use parentheses to group conditions which should be evaluated together.  But that's really all I can say.  You may want to submit a new question for that complex set of `WHERE` criteria.

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim A As String

Dim B As String

Dim p As String

A = Nz(Forms!frmsearchInv!txtDateFrom, "1")

B = Nz(Forms!frmsearchInv!txtDateFor, "1")

If A = "1" Then

A = "0000-01-01"

End If

If B = "1" Then

B = "9999-01-01"

End If

  p = "select * from orders where [orderDate] >= #" & A & "# AND [orderDate] <=#" & B & "# "
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  But, might you please [edit] your answer to give some textual explanation of how this answers the question?  A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712) of how this works would add to the long-term value of your answer.

Comment: Also, since you are doing string concatenation, your code may be vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://bobby-tables.com/msaccess).  See [Microsoft Access SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244693/3744182), [How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/3744182), [Avoiding SQL Injection in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50166009/3744182).

Comment: hello, I was searching for the same subject, finally I thought about the largest and the lowest acceptable date in access, when you want to show all data, you can put the largest acceptable date range, or you can put your own date from textbox , and its worked for me