# MS Access - UPDATE SQL Query Error 3061

Tags: sql, ms-access, inputbox

I try to update data in a table with text delivered from a InputBox.

```
Private Sub editname_Click()

 Dim GivenNameTB As String
 Dim EnterName As String
 Dim SQl As String
 Dim LocationID As Integer


 Me.txt_name.SetFocus
 GivenNameTB = Me.txt_name.Text
 EnterName = InputBox("Change name", "Change name", GivenNameTB)
 LocationID = Me.list_ma.Column(1)

 SQl = " Update tWorkers SET GivenName = forms!mainform!EnterName WHERE tWorkers.IDName = forms!mainform!LocationID "

 CurrentDb.Execute SQl




End Sub
```

However, I get error code 3061 "Too few parameters. Expected 2"

EDIT:

The table structure of **tWorkers**:

```
IDName - auto-increment (primary key)
LastName - text
GivenName - text
```

I'm targeting column **GivenName** by `SET GivenName = ...`, and the row by LocationID.

LocationID gets its value from the list field **list_ma**. The list field consists of five columns whereas IDName is column 2.

My whole point is to update a field in a table. A text box in my form shows a name which can be edited by clicking a button. Then a inputbox pops up. The entered string should be saved in the desired field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `DoCmd.RunSQL` rather than `CurrentDb.Execute`.

```
Private Sub editname_Click()

 Dim GivenNameTB As String
 Dim EnterName As String
 Dim SQl As String
 Dim LocationID As Integer

 Me.txt_name.SetFocus
 GivenNameTB = Me.txt_name.Text
 EnterName = InputBox("Change name", "Change name", GivenNameTB)
 LocationID = Me.list_ma.Column(1)

 SQL = " Update tWorkers SET GName = " & chr(34) & EnterName & chr(34) & " WHERE tWorkers.IDName = " & LocationID

 Debug.Print SQL -- For checking what code we are running.

 DoCmd.RunSQL SQL 

End Sub
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful. e.g. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/71392d23-867f-444f-a333-874b3f7eaea8/docmdrunsql-vs-dbexecute?forum=accessdev or http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/CurrentDbExecute-Docmd-t1654908.html&p=1654938#entry1654938

Comment: With DoCmd.RunSQL it works, but Access asks for allowance to update "0" records.

Somehow the identification via the ID IDName doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions? :/

Comment: The code does look a little odd to me. Can you show us your table structures, some sample data (anonymised if necessary) and let us know what the code we are correcting is supposed to do. As written it looks like it targets all the rows where the IDName field matches the LocationID on the form. That sounds odd, but not knowing your data makes it impossible to tell without further information.

Comment: I've made some edits which may help (not too sure). If you continue to have problems, please let us know the text which this code puts into the Immediate Window (can't see it? press CTRL+G).

Comment: I had to change char(34) to Chr(34) - None the less, it Works - Thank you!!

Comment: Ah yes, I tend to forget that VBA uses `chr` not `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Re-reading your question, your data lives in VBA variables, not in form controls. So you can't read the parameters from the form (`DoCmd.RunSQL` won't help).

You must construct the SQL string dynamically, best using [`CSql()` by Gustav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271) :

```
SQL = "Update tWorkers SET GivenName = " & CSql(EnterName) & _
      " WHERE tWorkers.IDName = " & CSql(LocationID)
Debug.Print SQL
CurrentDb.Execute SQL
```