# Filtering subform by date cant get it to accept date format

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have subform filters by VBA on user filling out text boxes,  it works by building the recordsource where statement.

It loops through the controls but when it comes to the date controls I am specifically the control to have it recognize 2 text boxes (from , to) for a single date field in the subform.

The issue I am having is its filtering on MM/DD/YY not DD/MM/YY and nothing I am trying seems to solve this.  I have tried adding formatting in the code to the sauce and to the text box value   .  also tried playing with the actual text box format but nothing seems to be making a difference and im pulling my hair out.

The relevant section of code is

```
    Dim strFilter As String
Dim ctL As Access.Control
For Each ctL In Me.Controls
If ctL.Name = "Raised_For_From" Then
If Not IsNull(Raised_For_From) Then
strFilter = strFilter & " AND " & "Raised_For" & " > " & "#" & Me.Raised_For_From & "#"
End If

Else

If ctL.Name = "Raised_For_To" Then
If Not IsNull(Raised_For_to) Then
strFilter = strFilter & " AND " & "Raised_For" & " < " & "#" &  Me.Raised_For_to & "#"
End If

Else
```

Comment: You could use Gustav's [`CSql()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271) when concatenating variables with SQL. It returns the correct date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always work with MM/DD/YY format in the SQL, and thus force the format of your dates accordingly :

```
strFilter = strFilter & " AND " & "Raised_For" & " > " & "#" & Format(Me.Raised_For_From,"MM/DD/YYYY") & "#"
```

If you don't get the proper results, chances are high that the dates in this table are wrong because when you INSERTED them you did not applied the format MM/DD

Comment: This was my problem, inputting the sauce wrong, ive gone back adjusted the initial record input to force MM/DD format and its working correctly now thank you