# Recordset is not updatable (query from two tables)

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint, ms-access-2013

I am using Microsoft Access 2013 with Sharepoint lists and I have two tables:

- **students**: ID, Full name, Mobile, Start_Date (the date that they start studying at my centre), and some irrelevant fields

=> there are many students with different starting dates

- **[Weeks Off]**: ID, Reason, From_Date (the date that the centre is temporarily closed), [Number of Weeks] (the number of weeks that the centre is temporariliy closed from that From_Date)

=> in each student' study time, they may have some "weeks off" that are not counted in the total number of weeks that they have studied for.

I am creating a query to calculate the number of weeks that students have studied from their `Start_Date`.

```
SELECT

students.ID,
students.[Full name],
students.Mobile,
students.Start_Date,
Round((Date()-students.[Start_Date])/7,0) - 
( SELECT SUM(
    IIF( [Weeks Off].[From Date]> students.[Start_Date] and [Weeks Off].[From Date]<Date(), 
         [Weeks Off].[Number of Weeks], 0 )
   ) 
  FROM [Weeks Off]
) AS [Studied Weeks],

FROM students;
```

The problem now is that even though the query successfully displays all students with a column showing their "Studied Weeks", the Recordset is not updatable.

How can I make it updatable again?

---

From comment:

I changed it into:

```
(Round( ( Date()- students.Start_Date)/7,0) - 
 DSum("[Number of Weeks]", "[Weeks Off]", 
      "[From Date]>= students.Start_Date And [From Date]<= Date()") 
) AS [Studied Weeks]
```

But it says: Microsoft cannot find the name students.Start_Date you entered in the expression. So I'm still stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

See: [Dealing with Non-Updateable Microsoft Access Queries](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html) and [Allen Browne: Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)

From the latter:

> It uses First(), Sum(), Max(), Count(), etc. in the SELECT clause. Queries that aggregate records are read-only.

It might work if you put the calculation into a separate query and join that (on Student.ID) to the Students table.

It will work (but may be slower) if you convert the SUM calculation into a `DSum()` expression. Then only that column will be read-only.

**Edit**

`students.Start_Date` is a variable in your `DSum` call, so it must be outside the constant string in the criteria.

Use Gustav's [`CSql()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271) to format the date and concatenate it with the rest.

```
(Round( ( Date()- students.Start_Date)/7,0) - 
 DSum("[Number of Weeks]", "[Weeks Off]", 
      "[From Date]>=" & CSql(students.Start_Date) & " And [From Date]<= Date()") 
) AS [Studied Weeks]
```

should do it.

Comment: Hi, I changed it into:


(Round(  (       Date()- students.Start_Date)/7,0) - DSum("[Number of Weeks]", "[Weeks Off]", "[From Date]>= students.Start_Date And [From Date]<= Date()") )    AS [Studied Weeks]

------------------- But it says:
Microsoft cannot find the name students.Start_Date you entered in the expression.

So I'm still stuck here.