# Issue opening form to a specific record for editing

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've been playing around trying several different things to get this form to open to a specific record.  So here's a little background first.
I have two forms, `frmWorkOrders` and `frmService`.  The first form (`frmWorkOrders`) creates a record in two tables, `tblWorkOrders` and `tblServiceRecord`.  The tables are linked (`tblServiceRecord` is the child table with a column called `WorkOrderID` that has a relationship to the `ID` field of `tblWorkOrders`).  I got it where the control (button) I was using would open `frmService` to the correct record but I was unable to edit the record at all.  So I messed around and broke the code where it's just not opening to the correct record anymore at all.  And I'm just not entirely sure what the heck I did wrong.  Here is the code to open `frmService`:

```
Private Sub cmdService_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdService_Click_Err

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmService", acNormal, , "WorkOrderID = " & Me!txtID, acNormal
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmWorkOrders"

cmdService_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdService_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdService_Click_Exit
End Sub
```

With this code, the form opens but it doesn't go to the proper record.  I had it originally as:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmService", acNormal, , "WorkOrderID = " & Me!txtID, acFormEdit
```

This opens to the correct record, but when I attempt to change anything in the other fields Access fires back an error "ding" and nothing happens.

Comment: Likely the error isn't in the open form code, but in the recordset for your frmService.  Try running the recordsource by itself; does it allow you to change or edit records there?

Comment: Or clicking the ... for the recordsource property, and in the query view, click Run.

Comment: Nope, doesn't let me edit anything.  What the heck would doing that?  It does return results

Comment: Bingo.  Your recordset isn't updatable.  That's likely the little error you're getting in the status bar.  Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127060/recordset-is-not-updatable-query-from-two-tables) for things to look for.  Once the recordset itself is updatable, the form should start working again.

Comment: Is Workorder id a text column, or a numbercolumn? If the column is text,then you need for the where clause  "WorkOrderID = '" & Me!txtID & "'"   (you have to add single quotes around the txtID expression).