# Access Form Combobox Partial Filter

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, filter, combobox

I'm trying to write a partial text match, to filter a form, from a combobox.

This is what I was working on writing:

```
"[FieldName1] Like '*" & Replace(Me.cboFindRecord.Text, "'", """) & "*' OR [FieldName2] Like '*" & Replace(Me.cboFindRecord.Text, "'", """) & "*'"
```

When I leave that line of the VBA code, I get an error at the 2nd & "*', highlighting the single quote ', and it says Compile error: Expected expression.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've checked the quotes and double quotes again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
, """)
```

is not a valid string.

If you want to use a double quote character, it would be

```
"[FieldName1] Like '*" & Replace(Me.cboFindRecord.Text, "'", """") & "*' OR ..."
```

(an escaped double quote inside a string)

But the usual way of escaping single quotes is to use two single quotes:

```
"[FieldName1] Like '*" & Replace(Me.cboFindRecord.Text, "'", "''") & "*' OR ..."
```

Comment: Thank you.  I realized I didn't really need the replace anyway.  People won't be trying to put in single quotes, into the filter. I was wasting my time, but at least you helped me get out of my own way hahaha.

Comment: Heh :) But I wouldn't rely on that, users can be ingenious. You can use Gustav's [`CSql()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271) when concatenating variables with SQL, it makes all this escaping and formatting much less painful.

Comment: thanks.  My stuff still isn't working, but I may be going about it the wrong way.  Just want a user to be able to type anything into a combo, and have it 1) auto expand (property is set to yes) and 2) to have any value in the displayed column filter to those that match any part of the string, so the user can filter in place.  Keep getting errors, but I'm debugging my way through them.  Unfortunate part is that as I type, I get the error, because I'm not getting to an acceptable value, and so I can't see if it is auto expanding like I want or not.