# Access Combo - Filter As You Type?

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter, combobox, refresh

I started a thread here: [Access Form Combobox Partial Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168630/access-form-combobox-partial-filter/45168875?noredirect=1#comment77306353_45168875) but it was a bit too specific, and now that I moved past that, I am struggling to get the behavior I want.

Here is the layout:

A form with the detail hidden.  The header has an unbound combobox for filtering the form. Once there is a filter to apply, that record is set for the filter on the form, and the detail is shown.  The users want to be able to type in the combo, for partial matches, instead of only being able to click the drop down and click to choose an option.

This is the rowsource of the combo:

```sql
SELECT [vw_Info_Records]![recordName] & " (" & [vw_Info_Records]![recordNo] & ")" AS frecord, vw_Info_Records.INF_RID
FROM vw_Info_Records
WHERE ((([vw_Info_Records]![recordName] & " (" & [vw_Info_Records]![recordNo] & ")") Like "*" & [Forms]![frmrecords]![cboFindrecord] & "*"))
ORDER BY [vw_Info_Records]![recordName] & " (" & [vw_Info_Records]![recordNo] & ")";
```

It is set to auto-expand Yes. It is not bound to anything, and limit to list is set to yes.

This is the onchange event:

```vb
Private Sub cboFindRecord_Change()
Dim MyCriteria As String

    If Me.cboFindRecord.SelStart > 0 Then
        Me.cboFindRecord.Dropdown
    End If

End Sub
```

This is the after update:

```vb
Private Sub cboFindRecord_AfterUpdate()
    Dim Criteria As String
    Dim myfilter As String

    If Me.cboFindRecord.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Me.Form.Filter = ""
        Me.FilterOn = False
        Me.Detail.Visible = False
    Else
        Criteria = "[INF_RID] = " & Me.cboFindRecord.Column(1)
        With Me.Form
            .Filter = Criteria
            .FilterOn = True
        End With
        Me.Detail.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

The first character that is typed in, makes the dropdown expand, and filter to any results that contain that character.  Any subsequent characters, and the drop down list doesn't update the filter to re-filter based on the added characters.  If I add a requery in the change, I get an error about saving the field, before I do a requery.  It wants me to set that "filter" value as a value for the combo, which I wouldn't do, because it's really an in string filter.  The user still needs to pick a value from whatever is left in the list, before I can filter the form to that record.

Thanks for any advice as to how to fix this!

Comment: Review http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Find-as-you-type. See link to code near the end of article.

Comment: That doesn't really help. The link to download the db & code doesn't work, because Allen's site is down. I tried going to his site already, during my research.

Comment: The code is available on another page of that same site. The link is toward the bottom of the article. Here it is http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Find-As-You-Type-%28CODE%29. And the database here http://new.allenbrowne.com/AppFindAsUType.html

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look.

Comment: so this uses a secondary textbox to do the filtering, which is not what I want.  I know I have seen filtering as you type in a combo, directly.  I just can't remember the method to do that.  i don't want users having to choose from the combo and a text box, when they really just want to filter or scroll through the same combo.

Comment: You want the user input to filter the form records as they type? Allen's setup uses the combobox to specify a field to restrict search and the textbox for input of parameter. Change the textbox control to a combobox, modify code for the combobox name. If you don't want to offer users the option to specify search field, then remove that combobox and modify code. Use combobox GotFocus event to trigger the dropdown..

Comment: I found what I was looking for, much more directly, and with way less code. It at least makes sense to me, so I went with this: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?&rat1=10&fid=6295