# Access VBA NoMatch = True when I think NoMatch should be False, Where am I going wrong?

Tags: ms-access, vba, findfirst, no-match

Through various kind souls @jericho johnson, and others.  I have VBA code that appears to be working.  Except for one part.  The final 'Else' condition, "Do While Not StrSQL1.NoMatch".  It always equals true.  Even if the value being referenced in the first Else statement "StrSQL1.FindFirst ([PrimaryKey] = qs.Fields("external_nmad_id"))"

When I hover over the 'external_nmad_id' it shows a string value.  When I hover over [PrimaryKey] it shows '[PrimaryKey]="" '.  Is the empty quote set referencing a recordset of values - or does that indicate that nothing is being referenced (hence why NoMatch is always True).  Or am I missing something elsewhere?

```
Public Sub EditFinalOutput2()

'set variables
Dim i As Long
Dim intCount As Long
Dim qs As DAO.Recordset
Dim ss As DAO.Recordset
Dim StrSQL1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim IRSfileFormatKey As String
Dim external_nmad_id As String
Dim nmad_address_1 As String
Dim nmad_address_2 As String
Dim nmad_address_3 As String
Dim mytestwrite As String
Dim PrimaryKey As String
Dim box13c_Address As String

'open reference set
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qs = db.OpenRecordset("SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest")

'turn popup messages off
'DoCmd.SetWarnings False

With qs.Fields

intCount = qs.RecordCount - 1
For i = 0 To intCount
'===
'=== Condition 1 Test - validate address
'===
If (IsNull(!nmad_address_1) Or (!nmad_address_1 = !nmad_city) Or 
(!nmad_address_1 = !Webir_Country) And IsNull(!nmad_address_2) Or 
(!nmad_address_2 = !nmad_city) Or (!nmad_address_2 = !Webir_Country) And 
IsNull(!nmad_address_3) Or (!nmad_address_3 = !nmad_city) Or 
(!nmad_address_3 = !Webir_Country)) Then
'=== Address Not Valid, insert into Review table
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Addresses_ToBeReviewed SELECT 
SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.* FROM SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest 
WHERE (((SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.external_nmad_id)='" & 
qs!external_nmad_id & "'));"

Else
Set StrSQL1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT RIGHT(IRSfileFormatKey, 10) As PrimaryKey, box13c_Address FROM 1042s_FinalOutput_7 WHERE 'PrimaryKey' = 'external_nmad_id';", dbOpenDynaset)
StrSQL1.FindFirst ([PrimaryKey] = qs.Fields("external_nmad_id"))
'===
'=== Condition 2 Test
'===
If StrSQL1.NoMatch Then
    '=== ID Not Found, insert into NotUsed table
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Addresses_NotUsed SELECT SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.* FROM SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest WHERE (((SunstarAccountsInWebir_SarahTest.external_nmad_id)='" & qs!external_nmad_id & "'));"

Else
    '=== Address Found, update record
    Do While Not StrSQL1.NoMatch
        StrSQL1.Edit
        StrSQL1.Fields("box13c_Address") = (qs.Fields("nmad_address_1") & qs.Fields("nmad_address_2") & qs.Fields("nmad_address_3"))
        StrSQL1.Update
    Loop
End If
....[more code below]
```

Comment: While I'm currently in a bootcamp it's primarily python-focused, I also work as an Analyst for a tax company - which is what this pertains to.  Due to ridiculous security constraints I can't send emails to @gmail accounts.  Most forums are blocked as well.  My help on work issues is either calling the dev department (different building and their time is valuable) and using stackoverflow.  I appreciate your time and help, I have a lot of bad syntax cuz most of my code is copy/pasted from examples online that I try to integrate

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues, this is probably the main one:

```
StrSQL1.FindFirst ([PrimaryKey] = qs.Fields("external_nmad_id"))
```

`FindFirst` takes a **string** as argument. What you have is an expression, which probably always evaluates to False or Null, since `[PrimaryKey]` is an undefined variable because it is outside of the string.

It should be

```
StrSQL1.FindFirst "[PrimaryKey] = " & CSql(qs.Fields("external_nmad_id").Value)
```

with `CSql()` from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271
It works for `external_nmad_id` being number or string.

To catch errors like this, put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module. 
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time.
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. 
This is really a must have for VBA development.

Other issues:

1) It is quite confusing to name a recordset variable `StrSQL1`.

2)

```
Do While Not StrSQL1.NoMatch
```

makes only sense if you do a `.FindNext` in the loop. Normally you always need `If` with `.NoMatch`.

3)

```
intCount = qs.RecordCount - 1
For i = 0 To intCount
    ' ...
    qs.MoveNext
Next i
```

is not a good way to do a recordset loop - `.RecordCount` is only reliably set after a `.MoveLast`. Use this instead:

```
Do While Not qs.EOF
    ' ...
    qs.MoveNext
Loop
```

It's simpler and reliable.