# Syntax error in UPDATE statement: value from String to Double

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using the following VBA code to update a Double field in my db. The name of the field is `week` and the name of the value to put on is `valore`. In my VBA they are both `String` variable.

When `valore` is a number without decimal (es. "15"), I have no problem.

When `valore` is a number with decimal (es. "2.5" or "2,5"), I get the following error:

> Syntax error in UPDATE statement

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Pianificazione risorse] " _
 & "SET " & week & " = " & CDbl(valore) & " " _
 & "WHERE [Codice Progetto] = '" & xCodice_Progetto & "' AND Risorsa = '" & xRisorsa & "';"
```

Answer (score 2):

Localization.

Try this in the immediate window:

```
? CDbl(1.5)
 1,5 

? CDbl(1,5)
*compile error*
```

Running an Italian version of Access, `CDbl` results, when converted to string, have a decimal comma. But Access SQL always expects decimal points (US format) for floating point numbers.

You should use parameters instead of concatenating strings:
[How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access)

If you really must, use Gustav's [`CSql()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271) when concatenating variables with SQL.

```
... & CSql(CDbl(valore)) & ...
```