# Passing SQL parameters containing spaces or hyphens

Tags: vba, ms-access

A) I'm collecting data from legacy applications; data elements are containing spaces and hyphens (CBR - CR - 22 - 2) or (CBR-CR-22-2)

B) In VBA, when building function and passing SQL parameters with those data elements, the code is generating errors (many!)

C) I narrowed down to identify that ALL errors were caused by the format of the data elements

D) The data element causing the problem is a PRIMARY KEY in about 30 tables and is generated by the legacy applications

(see code) I tried syntax:

A) `strDataElm`

B) `[strDataElm]`

C) `& """ & strDataElm & """`

```
strSourceSql = "SELECT " & strSourceFld & " FROM " & strSourceTbl & " WHERE " & strSourceFld & " = " & strDataElm
```

in the immediate window it gives

```
    SELECT NumeroCtl FROM tblLnkCtrl WHERE RISKID = CBR - CR - 22 - 2
```

In a ideal world, I'd like the strDataElm being passed as is i.e. `CBR - CR - 22 2` or without spaces `CBR-CR-22-2`; removing the hyphens would bring issues because the data is a primary key and reused in other applications..

Comment: Start by using actual parameters, and not concatenating strings. See [How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/7296893)

Comment: If data type of strSourceFld is string then you should put it in single quotes: ... RISKID = 'CBR - CR - 22 - 2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is mentioned it is better to use parametrized queries, but I know - way to concatenate string is too pleasurable.

Try this:

```
strSourceSql = "SELECT " & strSourceFld & " FROM " & strSourceTbl & " WHERE [" & strSourceFld & "] = [" & strDataElm & "]"
```

if you pass the field reference

And this, if  you pass the value itself

```
strSourceSql = "SELECT " & strSourceFld & " FROM " & strSourceTbl & " WHERE " & strSourceFld & " = " & "'" &  strDataElm & "'"
```

Comment: Very true... using " ' " did solve the issue... I promise to try parametrized queries; I the present case, I would have  to build as many queries as fields in the initial tables....

Comment: If you must, then please use Gustav's [`CSql()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271) when concatenating variables with SQL. @jm_lux8832

Comment: Thanks to All. I made good use of ALL the above including the lovely piece of wonder found at http://allenbrowne.com/func-06.html