# Query for text in a shortext field returns "Type Mismatch"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to populate ADODB Recordset, from a user input in a MS-Access form.
The data type the field in Access table **shortext**.
The data I am trying to get from the form input is also a text.

```
queryString="select * From tableshoporder where shopordernumber=" & me.txtInputShoporder.Value
adodb.recordset.open queryString,currentdb.connection,adopendynamic,adlockoptimistic
```

The above query throws "type mismatch error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you state

> The data type of the field in the Access table is **short text**. The data I am trying to get from the form input is also text.

You'll need to supply the value surrounded by string delimiters, e.g. either using single quotes:

```
queryString="select * From tableshoporder where shopordernumber='" & me.txtInputShoporder.Value & "'"
```

Or double quotes:

```
queryString="select * From tableshoporder where shopordernumber=""" & me.txtInputShoporder.Value & """"
```

However, note that this will break if `me.txtInputShoporder.Value` itself contains string delimiters. To avoid this, you can either use Gustav's [cSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/7531598), or use [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49509616/7531598).

Comment: Correct,sorry took me so long to reply