# Basic Visual Basic Program Error - Probably Variable/ Syntax Error (marked Fat)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, recordset

This is the edited code, with Gutav´s function and the implemented code from André.

It still seems to not work without an error. I'm clueless.

New code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Form_Load()
    
    Dim rs          As Recordset
    Dim rs2         As Recordset
    Dim Werte       As String
    Dim Datums_variable As Date
    Dim actual_date As Date
    Dim id          As Integer
    Dim strSql      As String
    
    actual_date = Date
    
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from query_offene_wartungspunkte ", dbOpenDynaset)
    
    Me.Test_Liste.RowSourceType = " Value List "
    
    Do Until rs.EOF
        
        Werte = rs!intervall
        
        Select Case Werte
            
            Case "jährlich"
                Datums_variable = actual_date - 365
            Case "halbjährlich"
                Datums_variable = actual_date - 180
            Case "monatlich"
                Datums_variable = actual_date - 31
            Case "wöchentlich"
                Datums_variable = actual_date - 7
            Case "täglich"
                Datums_variable = actual_date - 1
            Case "vierteljährlich"
                Datums_variable = actual_date - 90
                
        End Select
        
        id = rs!id
        
        strSql = "select * from query_offene_wartungspunkte " & _
                 "where [Date] > " & CSql(Datums_variable) & " And id = " & id
        Debug.Print strSql

        Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)
        
        If Not rs2.EOF Then
            Werte = " Arbeitsplatz/Maschine: " & rs2!arbeitsplatz_maschine & " ArbeitsplatzNr: " & rs2!arbeitsplatz_nr
            Me.Test_Liste.AddItem (Werte)
            
        Else
            ' rs2 is empty
            
            
        End If
        
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub


Public Function CSql( _
       ByVal Value As Variant) _
       As String
    
    #If Win32 Then
        ' Serves only to make the code compile unmodified in 32-bit VBA
        ' which misses the constant VBA.vbLongLong.
        Const vbLongLong    As Integer = 20
    #End If
    
    Const SqlNull           As String = " Null"
    
    Dim Sql                 As String
    
    Select Case VarType(Value)
        Case vbEmpty        '    0  Empty (uninitialized).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbNull        '    1  Null (no valid data).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbInteger        '    2  Integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbLong        '    3  Long integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbSingle        '    4  Single-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDouble        '    5  Double-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbCurrency        '    6  Currency.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDate        '    7  Date.
            Sql = Format(Value, " \#yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss\#")
        Case vbString        '    8  String.
            Sql = Replace(Trim(Value), "'", "''")
            If Sql = "" Then
                Sql = SqlNull
            Else
                Sql = "        '" & Sql & "'"
            End If
        Case vbObject        '    9  Object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbError        '   10  Error.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbBoolean        '   11  Boolean.
            Sql = Str(Abs(Value))
        Case vbVariant        '   12  Variant (used only with arrays of variants).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDataObject        '   13  A data access object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDecimal        '   14  Decimal.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbByte        '   17  Byte.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbLongLong        '   20  LongLong integer (Relevant in 64-bit VBA only).
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbUserDefinedType        '   36  Variants that contain user-defined types.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbArray        ' 8192  Array. Ignored.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case Else        '       Should not happen.
            Sql = SqlNull
    End Select
    
    CSql = Sql & " "
    
End Function
```

Can someone help me please?

---

Like this:

```
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from query_offene_wartungspunkte where Date > " & Datums_variable & " AND id = " & id = " & id, dbOpenDynaset)
```

I've tried this but it also throws an error

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683.

Comment: Should be `Date > " & Datums_variable & " AND id = " & id`

Comment: like this:    Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from querry_offene_wartungspunkte where Date > " & Datums_variable & " AND id = " & id = " & id, dbOpenDynaset)

Comment: ive triedd this but it give out an error as well.

Comment: Date parameter values need to be enclosed in single quotes, or, for MS Access, pound signs (#).

Comment: Date constants are enclosed inside # in ACCESS.

Comment: I am sorry to ask, but could you provide the full code with your solution, since very new in VBA and i cant seem to get it implemented right...

Comment: What is the error / problem? What is the output of `Debug.Print strSql` ? (Use Ctrl+g to see it).

Comment: this is the output:      select * from query_offene_wartungspunkte where [Date] >  #2020/12/12 00:00:00#  And id = 2

Comment: Laufzeitfehler 3061
1 Parameter wurden erwartet, aber es wurden zu wenig Parameter übergeben

Answer (score -1):

If you want to concatenate variables with SQL, use Gustav's [`CSql()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271) .
It handles dates, strings and other variables.

```
strSql = "select * from query_offene_wartungspunkte " & _
         "where [Date] > " & CSql(Datums_variable) & " AND id = " & id
Debug.Print strSql
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)
```

Why `Debug.Print`? See [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

The correct way to check if the recordset has rows is:

```
If Not rs2.EOF Then
    ' use values
Else
    ' rs2 is empty
End If
```

Comment: I am sorry to ask, but could you provide the full code with your solution, since very new in VBA and i cant seem to get it implemented right...

Comment: Andre i have edited the code as u suggested, but it gives out following error while debugging: CSql function not declared

Comment: I linked the function, you need to copy it into a code module.

Comment: i updated the Code, could you please take a look?

Comment: select * from query_offene_wartungspunkte where [Date] >  #2020/12/10 00:00:00#  And id = 2

Comment: Looks ok, what is the problem?