# Using Variables in a MSAccess Function with SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, variables

I'm struggling with entering a custom made ID number on all my tables to link all records together, trying out normalization.

I have an *EmployeeDetails* table and a *LoginDetails* table. Its my understanding that I need a field called *EmployeeID* on both and I can use the SQL Select code I have to pull the data like on other forms. *Username* is the field name also in the *LoginDetails* table and *txt_Username* is the username's textbox on the login page.

For now I just put this on the login screen to troubleshoot, but it will end up being called when a new employee is created. Only problem is my knowledge on how to include a variable within the SQL line, ie:

```
Function newID(frm As Form)

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    index = 12345
         
    db.Execute "UPDATE LoginDetails " & "SET EmployeeID = index " & "WHERE Username = frm.txt_username.Value;"

End Function
```

I've tried for about 2-3 days, maybe a couple of hours here and there to get it to work but I'm starting to get demotivated. I managed to write a line of SQL that had a static value as the EmployeeID, but as soon as you add VB Variables in the mix it dosen't like it.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `Username = '" & frm.txt_username.Value & "';"`

Comment: `"UPDATE LoginDetails SET EmployeeID =" & index  & " WHERE Username = '" & frm.txt_username.Value & "'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the SQL line as a string that contains the SQL command.

The SQL part (table name, column name) is static , and you need to concatenate the variable you get from access to it. So your line would be:

```
db.Execute "UPDATE LoginDetails SET EmployeeID = " & index & " WHERE Username = '" & frm.txt_username.Value & "';"
```

Also, it's good to leave a space before SQL keywords when concatenating (prevents problem at execution time).

Comment: You're missing the `&` in username...

Comment: Amazing thank you. I know VBA but not SQL as much. Are you able to tell me why I need to put the textbox.value in 2 quotation marks? Is one for the textbox and the other for SQL?

Comment: The value is of string type

Comment: Single quotes are identifiers for strings in SQL. They (mostly) serve the same purpose as double quotes in VBA.

Comment: Beware of errors if the concatenated value itself contains `'`. Use parameters or use Gustav's [`CSql()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271) when concatenating variables with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

db.Execute "UPDATE LoginDetails " & "SET EmployeeID = " & index & " WHERE Username = '" & frm.txt_username.Value &"'; "