# Updating a date/time field in MS Access using VBA

Tags: vba, datetime, ms-access, sql-update

I'm trying to update a date/time field when a new file is imported through vba.

It works for the first file, but for subsequent imports I get a type mismatch error.

If I delete the 'FileDate' field and re-insert it, it works for the first time, but after I get the error again.

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    
    Dim str_table As String
    Dim str_sql As String
    
    Dim dt As Date

    str_table = "Items"

    dt = CDate(Format(FileDateFromPath(file_path), "MM/DD/YYYY"))
    
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    
    str_sql = "UPDATE [" & str_table & "] SET [FileDate] = #" & dt & "# " & _
        "WHERE [FileDate] Is Null OR [FileDate]='';"
   
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            TransferType:=acImport, _
            SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
            TableName:=str_table, _
            FileName:=file_path, _
            HasFieldNames:=True ' or False if no headers
    
    db.Execute str_sql, dbFailOnError '<-- error here's
```

I've tried different formats for the date (DD/MM/YYYY, changed to MM/DD/YYYY), I've included # around the date...

Deleting the field and re-inserting it works, but only for the first time...

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your `dt` variable is a Date, not a String. Therefore the Format you apply has no effect, and when you concat the variable, it will use your local date format.

Use Gustav's [`CSql()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271) when concatenating variables with SQL.

Also, a date column can not have the value `''`, so you can omit that.

```
str_sql = "UPDATE [" & str_table & "] SET [FileDate] = " & CSql(dt) & _
         " WHERE [FileDate] Is Null;"
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, but still having problems. I think it must be a problem/bug with the table, as if i delete the 'FileDate' field, and put it back in, it works for the first time, but then the type miss-match error returns.

I will try a new table, or if i can't get that to work, use a temporary table when importing the data.