# Use me.filter with 2 conditions - numeric and text

Tags: ms-access

I have created a button to filter records to be below a certain number AND with a specific category.   I can't get it to work.

The code I have used is:

```
Private Sub KIAResearch_Click()
Dim strsc As String
strsc = "Killed in Action"
Me.Filter = "WikiDegrees BETWEEN " & 1 & " AND " & 8 & " And Service Category=" & strsc
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Avoid column names with spaces - if you must use them, you need square brackets in SQL: `[Service Category]`.

To safely concatenate variables with SQL, use Gustav's [`CSql()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271). It handles strings (which need quotes) and other variables.

So:

```
strFilter = "WikiDegrees BETWEEN " & 1 & " AND " & 8 & " And [Service Category]=" & CSql(strsc)
Debug.Print strFilter
Me.Filter = strFilter
```