# How to search for all values in one table in multiple fields in another table and update or create a new table in MS Access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to create an MS Access database for our accounting.

I import a bank transfers summary from our bank as a CSV file and import it temporary to Table2 (TmpBankImport).

I would like to automate and add a code to the recurring transactions. I want to do this by creating a Table1 (Codes) where I put in a unique string value that is a part of the value from different fields of Table2 (TmpBankImport) AKA ACCOUNTNR, DESCRIPTION, REFERENCE. So as a result I want to create a Table3 (BankReady) where the CODE and TOCHECK is set.

How can I search for all the keywords that are in Table1 in all the Table2 fields and create Table3 in MS Access 2016?

Example of the database:

Tabel1 (Codes)

| SEARCHFOR | CODE | TOCHECK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ALDI | ALD | N |
| PAYPAL | PAP | Y |
| LIDL | LDL | N |
| REF:888 | DDL | N |
| BE88.8888.888 | SSD | Y |
| 0123456 | BBL | N |

Table2 (TmpBankImport)

| ACCOUNTNR | DESCRIPTION | REFERENCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BE22.2222.222 | Purchase ALDI | REF: 111111111 |
| BE33.3333.333 | Purchase BRICO | PURCHASE 0123456 |
| BE44.5555.777 | PayPal (Europe) | S. C.MED: 999999 |
| BE11.1234.123 | SECURITY SERV. | SERVICE NR:23232323 |
| BE22.2222.222 | Purchase ALDI | REF: 22222222 |
| BE33.4444.555 | Purchase LIDL | SOME REFERENCE Nr |
| BE77.7777.777 | GOOGLE INC | Google App REF:888 |
| BE88.8888.888 | PC ONLINE SHOP | Reference ID:blabla |

Expecting Table3 (BankReady)

| ACCOUNTNR | DESCRIPTION | REFERNCE | CODE | TOCHECK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BE22.2222.222 | Purchase ALDI | REF: 111111111 | ALD | N |
| BE33.3333.333 | Purchase BRICO | PURCHASE 0123456 | BBL | N |
| BE44.5555.777 | PayPal (Europe) | S. C.MED: 999999 | PAP | Y |
| BE11.1234.123 | SECURITY SERV. | SERVICE NR:23232323 |  | Y |
| BE22.2222.222 | Purchase ALDI | REF: 22222222 | ALD | N |
| BE33.4444.555 | Purshase LIDL | SOME REFERENCE Nr | LDL | N |
| BE77.7777.777 | GOOGLE INC | Google App REF:888 | DDL | N |
| BE88.8888.888 | PC ONLINE SHOP | Reference ID:blabla | SSD | Y |

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this with separate UDPATE statements, one for each row in the Codes table.

First insert all TmpBankImport records into BankReady, with NULL for TOCHECK.

Then do a recordset loop over Codes, and build each SQL in VBA like this:

```vb
strSearch = " '*" & RS!SEARCHFOR & "*'"

S = "UPDATE BankReady " & vbCrLf & _
    "SET CODE = '" & RS!CODE & "', TOCHECK = '" &  RS!TOCHECK & "'" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE TOCHECK IS NULL AND " & vbCrLf & _       ' make sure to only process new records
    " (    ACCOUNTNR   LIKE " & strSearch & vbCrLf & _
    "   OR DESCRIPTION LIKE " & strSearch & vbCrLf & _
    "   OR REFERNCE    LIKE " & strSearch & ")" 

Debug.Print S    ' see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271
DB.Execute S
```

And finally process all rows that didn't find any match:

```
UPDATE BankReady SET TOCHECK = 'Y' WHERE TOCHECK IS NULL
```

---

If anything in the Codes table may ever include an `'`, use Gustav's [`CSql()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494189/3820271) instead of concatenating the apostrophes.

---

If you have multiple search expressions per Code, add them as separate rows in the Codes table. Then you need to process them *from specific to generic*.
E.g. first `REF:8888123`, then `REF:888`

You can do this by adding a `Sorting` column that you fill manually.
Or if all variations are like the example, you can load the Codes recordset loop with this sort order:

```
ORDER BY Code, Len(SEARCHFOR) DESC
```

(First ordering by code makes debugging easier.)

Comment: Thank you for the Answer that helped a lot.  How to do this with a SEARCHFOR1 and SEARCHFOR2 field so that if SEARCHFOR2 has also a value then both values should be found to give it a code ?   This to rule out if i have a 'REF:888' SEARCHFOR value and there would be a  REF:888 and a REF:8888123 record it would find both. But with a second SEARCHFOR value i could filter it better. But the SEARCHFOR2 is not always given, , it can be empty (null). Thanks for your time.

Comment: That would be bad design. 1..n data points should always be rows, not columns. See edited answer. @guntherherremans