# DAO recordset filter function cannot filter with 2 properties

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, dao

I am using VBA in MS Access 2010.

I am currently trying to filter from a recordset with 2 fields.
However i tired, it will not filter as per what i want.

But if i were to filter based on only one field, the recordset is able to filter accordingly.

This is what I have now.

```
Private Function getCheckedRecordsFromDB(ByVal cmNum As String) As Boolean
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim rsFiltered As Recordset
    Dim iSeral As Integer

    'Gets different fields from different tables and store them into rs
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("QueryMemoOutFrm")

    ' Its not working during the filtering, keeps returning nothing found
    rs.Filter = "Doctype='Outgoing' AND DocumentRef='" & cmNum & "'"
    Set rsFiltered = rs.OpenRecordset

    Do While Not rsFiltered.EOF
        ' Do Something
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    rsFiltered.Close
    Set rsFiltered = Nothing
End Function
```

I have read the documentation on MSDN, and does not see where did i go wrong. (Maybe i've missed out something)

Comment: You've got a typo there: `rs.Filter` not `rs.Fliter`. Is that representative of the actual code?

Comment: Sorry, have corrected that mistake.
That mistake is not representative of the actual code

Comment: What's the field type of the `DocumentRef` field?

Comment: Does it work if use use just one or the other filters?

Comment: `DocumentRef` is `string`
Yes, it does works if using only just one of the filters. Either one will works, but not both

Comment: Opps, input wrong. corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the codes a little bit and it works. But not sure why though.

```
Private Function getCheckedRecordsFromDB(ByVal cmNum As String) As Boolean
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim rsFiltered As Recordset
    Dim dSerial As Double

    'Gets different fields from different tables and store them into rs
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("QueryMemoOutFrm")

    rs.Filter = "Doctype='Outgoing' AND DocumentRef='" & cmNum & "'"
    Set rsFiltered = rs.OpenRecordset

    ' newly added
    rsFiltered.MoveFirst

        Do While Not rsFiltered.EOF
            dSerial = rsFiltered!SerialNo
            rsFiltered.MoveNext
        Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    rsFiltered.Close
    Set rsFiltered = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Strange. `Option Explicit`? Why 2 recordsets and not using a where condtion in rs? And of course use [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access)

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to troubleshoot if your provide your actual code via copy/paste.
That being said, I'm just wondering why you're using two recordsets?
Do you get the proper answer if you actually do your loop on the real filtered recordset?

Eliminate the line

```
Set rsFiltered = rs.OpenRecordset
```

Use this block of code on **rs** instead of **rsFiltered**

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
    ' Do Something
Loop
```

Comment: You recognised the dot between rs and Filter? But where condition would be more common.

Comment: Its the actual code provided. I can't copy and paste as I'm developing on another laptop which is not supposed to be air-gap.