# Creating data entry form using button VBA

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I am trying to create a basic data entry form, however, it is turning into more trouble than I anticipated..  I have the form created, now I am just trying to INSERT the data into the DB (TEST).  I am receiving an "Object Required" error.  Any suggestions? All of the txt boxes are verified to be correct.  This is all being done through Access VBA

```
Private Sub Command28_Click()



Dim sSQL As String

Set sSQL = "INSERT INTO TEST (Carrier_Ent_ID, Row_Insert_TS, Row_Update_TS, 
            Row_Insert_User_ID, Row_Update_User_ID, Carrier_Ent_Name, Active) 
VALUES (" & Me.txtENTID & "," & Me.txtDate & "," & Me.txtDate & "," & 
            Me.cmboUserID & "," & Me.cmboUserID & "," & Me.txtENTNAME & "," 
          & Me.Txtactive & "); "


DoCmd.RunSQL.sSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't done any access for a long time, but I'm pretty sure you need apostrophes for strings (') and maybe # for date/time?  Also it'd be worth looking into parameterized queries.

Comment: NDJ seems right.   Instead of running the SQL, print it out instead. The error will be easy to spot, no ' in values line seems right.  If you can't get it from there, post whatever print sSQL returns and we can go from there

Comment: Is that exactly as it appears in the VBE?  You've got no line continuation characters.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook no, I have the SQL all on one line

Comment: You are setting a string, strings are not objects and cannot be set.  Try removing that.

Comment: Thank you @jeffrey and everyone else as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see there's a couple of mistakes in the code.

You only use `SET` when setting a reference to an object - sSQL is a text string.
`DoCmd.RunSQL` shouldn't have a full-stop after `RunSQL`- just the text string.
If `Me.txtENTNAME` is a text string it should have an apostrophe before and after it.

```
Private Sub Command28_Click()

    Dim sSQL As String

    'No Set & ' before and after Me.txtENTNAME (assuming it's text).
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO TEST (Carrier_Ent_ID, Row_Insert_TS, Row_Update_TS, " & _
           "Row_Insert_User_ID, Row_Update_User_ID, Carrier_Ent_Name, Active) " & _
           "VALUES (" & Me.txtENTID & "," & Me.txtDate & "," & Me.txtDate & "," & _
           Me.cmboUserID & "," & Me.cmboUserID & ",'" & Me.txtENTNAME & "'," & Me.txtActive & "); "

    'No full stop after RunSQL.
    DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Add [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access) to prevent errors by by wrong values entered (e.g.  quotes in `Me.txtENTNAME`).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Good link for the parameters.