# Mainform tab control passing value to subform variable for select case

Tags: ms-access, subform

I've been searching this for the last three hours, so I'm sorry if this has been asked and answered, but I can't find the solution.

I have a mainform, `frmPHDLP` and subform (continuous datasheet) `frmPHDUpdate`. Neither are bound forms. `frmPHDLP` has a tab control on it which displays real world office locations. The subform will display a list of employees at each location based on the tab selected. I am setting the RecordSource in the subform in VBA.

The first tab works perfect. The problem is, when I choose a new tab on the mainform, I cannot get the subform to requery the SQL with the new location. The SQL statement is built in the `Form_Current` event of the subform.

Apparently running `Me!frmPHDUpdate.Form.Requery` does not fire the `Form_Current` event on the subform. Because why would it?

THREE HOURS. Nada. Thanks for any help.

frmPHDLP Code:

```
Private Sub tabOffices_Change()
    Me!frmPCLPUpdateSF.Requery

End Sub
```

frmPHDUpdate Code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    Select Case Me.Parent!tabOffices.Value
        Case 0
            strSearch = "8401"
        Case 1
            strSearch = "8400"
        Case 2
            strSearch = "8403"
        Case 3
            strSearch = "8402"
        Case 4
            strSearch = "8404"
        Case 5
            strSearch = "8405"
        Case 6
            strSearch = "8413"
        Case 7
            strSearch = "8411"
    End Select

    strSQL = "SELECT tblEmployee.ID, tblEmployee.[LastName] & "", "" & [FirstName] AS EmpName, tblPHDLProgram.MemberOfPHDL, tblOffices.OfficeID FROM tblOffices INNER JOIN (tblPHDLP RIGHT JOIN tblEmployee ON tblPHDLP.ID = tblEmployee.ID) ON tblOffices.ID = tblEmployee.Office WHERE (((tblOffices.OfficeID)= " & strSearch & "));"
    Me.RecordSource = strSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you building the SQL in the Current event? Why don't you just have a sub that builds the SQL that you can trigger manually, and on any event you wish? Why are you even building SQL at all (you can just refer to a control on the main form in the SQL)? Please share some code.

Comment: >Why are you even building SQL at all (you can just refer to a control on the main form in the SQL)?
I'm not really sure what you mean. Can you give an example? If it works, I'd love to try it!

Comment: You can see [this answer (first section)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49509616/7296893). It's a good practice, since it avoids many errors with string concatenation. That does require you to move the `SELECT CASE` to a `Switch`, but it could certainly work for you.

Comment: I've provided a more detailed explanation for how to use referring to a control in your specific case in my answer to avoid building and changing the SQL clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your code more modular. Also, you should not change the forms recordsource on Form_Current, since that requeries the form, and triggers another current, and that triggers an infinite loop. This might all be caused by Access avoiding that infinite loop.

frmPHDUpdate Code:

```
Public Sub BuildSQL()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Select Case Me.Parent!tabOffices.Value
        Case 0
            strSearch = "8401"
        Case 1
            strSearch = "8400"
        Case 2
            strSearch = "8403"
        Case 3
            strSearch = "8402"
        Case 4
            strSearch = "8404"
        Case 5
            strSearch = "8405"
        Case 6
            strSearch = "8413"
        Case 7
            strSearch = "8411"
    End Select
    strSQL = "SELECT tblEmployee.ID, tblEmployee.[LastName] & "", "" & [FirstName] AS EmpName, tblPHDLProgram.MemberOfPHDL, tblOffices.OfficeID FROM tblOffices INNER JOIN (tblPHDLP RIGHT JOIN tblEmployee ON tblPHDLP.ID = tblEmployee.ID) ON tblOffices.ID = tblEmployee.Office WHERE (((tblOffices.OfficeID)= " & strSearch & "));"
    Me.RecordSource = strSQL
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.BuildSQL
End Sub
```

frmPHDLP Code:

```
Private Sub tabOffices_Change()
    Me!frmPCLPUpdateSF.Form.BuildSQL
End Sub
```

Or, even better: move your case statement to the subforms SQL:

As the record source for frmPHDUpdate

```
SELECT tblEmployee.ID, tblEmployee.[LastName] & "", "" & [FirstName] AS EmpName, tblPHDLProgram.MemberOfPHDL, tblOffices.OfficeID 
FROM tblOffices 
INNER JOIN (tblPHDLP RIGHT JOIN tblEmployee ON tblPHDLP.ID = tblEmployee.ID) ON tblOffices.ID = tblEmployee.Office 
WHERE tblOffices.OfficeID = Switch(
    Forms!frmPHDLP!tabOffices = 0, 8401,
    Forms!frmPHDLP!tabOffices = 1, 8400,
    Forms!frmPHDLP!tabOffices = 2, 8403,
    Forms!frmPHDLP!tabOffices = 3, 8402,
    Forms!frmPHDLP!tabOffices = 4, 8404,
    Forms!frmPHDLP!tabOffices = 5, 8405,
    Forms!frmPHDLP!tabOffices = 6, 8413,
    Forms!frmPHDLP!tabOffices = 7, 8411
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it into the sub and it creates the correct SQL statement when I `debug.print` it. The subform information does not change when I change tabs though. I put a `Me!frmPCLPUpdateSF.Form.Requery` after the `Me!frmPCLPUpdateSF.Form.BuildSQL` statement, but nothing.

Comment: Basic debugging: does tabOffices_Change fire correctly (add a debug.print in there)? Add a `Debug.Print Me.Recordsource` at the end of the BuildSQL. Does that change correctly as well?

Comment: `tabOffices_Change` fires correctly. I added  the debug at the end of `BuildSQL`. It's cycling through on `Form_Load` six times, then on `tabOffices_Change` four times. Weird. Each time, the SQL statement is correct though, it's just not populating the form.

Comment: See the current edit. Avoid setting the recordset on form current, that causes an infinite loop, and access's tricks to break out of it are likely causing problems.

Comment: OK, that fixed the multiple run throughs, but it's still not populating the subform when I change the tab. Again, the SQL statement is correct.

Comment: Hm.. I can't reproduce this. Instead of `Me.RecordSource = strSQL` you could try `Set Me.Recordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)`

Comment: That gave me an "Invalid use of property" error. Grr.. I have realized that in the time I've spent trying to get this to work, I could have just created seven different forms instead of doing it through programming. But I still want to know why this isn't working. Should be easy!

Comment: I'm at a total loss then. Never got an invalid use of property when setting a forms recordset. If frmPHDUpdate is a simple datasheet form, nothing more, then I don't understand why it's behaving this way.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I can't figure it out... I might have to walk away for a bit.. I'm fearing for my computer!

Comment: If you could share a sample section of the database (with as minimal data as possible), I could try debugging it. But maybe tomorrow, been at it too long too.

Comment: One of the subforms is now updating! The properties are exactly the same as the others. Ugh. Thanks for the offer, but I can't really share the data. Awfully sensitive!!!

Comment: OMG. I figured it out. Another Select Case under `tabOffices_Change`. Based on the tab, it's `Me!subX.Forms.Requery` where subX=the subform name. Thanks again for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out *MasterLinkFields/ChildLinkFields*.

I guess you could use *tabOffices* and *OfficeID* and remove all of this code.

Comment: Can't use those fields as the forms are not bound to anything.

Also, `tabOffices` <> `OfficeID`. `tabOffices` = index of the page, so I'm using the `Select Case` to assign the proper OfficeID.

Comment: @Scott Create a table where you assign the tabOffices and OfficeID  then use it in the forms query is what Gustav suggest.

Comment: 1: The main form doesn't have to be bound. 2: The subform is set bound to your recordset. Do that initially.