# MS Access - Docmd.OpenReport

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to open a report with date field between two dates (dateFrom & dateTo) which comes from the textboxes in a form.

```
dateFrom = Forms!formOptions!txtDateFrom.Value
dateTo = Forms!formOptions!txtDateTo.Value
```

Have tried:

(Edit:)

> with and without the '#' around the dateFrom and dateTo variables
>
> & with and without the [] around the field name, and still cannot get
>   this to work.

When I try this code:

```
strCriteria = "[ActionTime] >= '" & dateFrom & "' And [ActionTime] <= '" & dateTo & "'"
DoCmd.OpenReport "reportLog", acViewReport, , strCriteria
```

An 'Enter a parameter value' dialog will popup, I've checked the control source of the report & the field name is correct & there are no sorting or grouping happening either.

And when I put a pair of extra ' ' around the field name in the above code to be:

```
strCriteria = "'[ActionTime]' >= '" & dateFrom & "' And '[ActionTime]' <= '" & dateTo & "'"
DoCmd.OpenReport "reportLog", acViewReport, , strCriteria
```

The report opens normally but instead of just the record between the dates, all of the records appear.

Have also tried using the WhereCondition:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "reportLog", acViewReport, , WhereCondition:="'[ActionTime] >= #" & dateFrom & "# AND [ActionTime] <= #" & dateTo & "#'"
```

And the report opens normally but with all the records, not following the WhereCondition.

I don't know which part of this coding is false, have referred to other sites but still can't detect what's exactly wrong. Would be grateful for any guidance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need properly formatted string expressions for your date values:

```
Dim dateFrom As Date
Dim dateTo As Date

dateFrom = DateValue(Forms!formOptions!txtDateFrom.Value)
dateTo = DateValue(Forms!formOptions!txtDateTo.Value)

strCriteria = "[ActionTime] >= #" & Format(dateFrom, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And [ActionTime] <= #" & Format(dateTo, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
Debug.Print "'" & strCriteria & "'"
DoCmd.OpenReport "reportLog", acViewReport, , strCriteria
```

Edit: If ActionTime appears more than once, try:

```
strCriteria = "[reportLog].[ActionTime] >= #" & Format(dateFrom, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And [reportLog].[ActionTime] <= #" & Format(dateTo, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Comment: Tried this, but the 'Enter parameter value' dialog is still popping-up. I thought perhaps because it can't recognize [ActionTime], and added [reportLog]! in front of the [ActionTime] to be like [reportLog]![ActionTime], this time the dialog did not pop-up and the report opens, but it still doesn't follow the date criteria. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Then `[ActionTime]` is misspelled or isn't a field in the recordsource of the report.

Comment: I've checked multiple times and `[ActionTime]` is the exact same name of the field in both the report and also the table, and yes the spelling is the same. I don't know what else is causing this.

Comment: Check the criteria string - see Debug.Print in the edited answer.

Comment: I've also checked using debug before. And this is what comes up in the immediate window. `[ActionTime] >= #05/22/2018# AND [ActionTime] <= #05/23/2018#.` I formatted the date as mm/dd/yyyy as that's what the date format is for the field `[ActionTime]`.

Comment: A date value carries no format. The purpose of Format is to create a string expression for a date value that will always be understood correctly by Access SQL. But I noticed your first comment, so see edited answer, please.

Comment: I deleted the report, and made another one and also re-wrote the code, following what you advised. And it seems to work. I don't know why it didn't before. So, I'll accept this as an answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The shared attempts won't work. The first, because dates are supposed to be formatted in a specific way (YYYY-MM-DD or MM/DD/YYYY) and surrounded by `#` (the value, not the field name). The second, because you're comparing the literal string `'[ActionTime]'` to a string containing a date, and that's not a very sensible thing to do.

However, the easy and safe way to do this is just to set parameters:

```
strCriteria = "[ActionTime] >= dateFrom And [ActionTime] <=  dateTo"
DoCmd.SetParameter "dateFrom", dateFrom
DoCmd.SetParameter "dateTo", dateTo
DoCmd.OpenReport "reportLog", acViewReport, , strCriteria
```

Read more about using parameters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49509616/7296893).

Comment: what I meant was that I tried with and without the # around the dateFrom & dateTo variables. And also with and without the [] around the field name. Will edit the question.

Comment: But ActionTime in this report is taken from a table, and in the table, the type for this field is date, is it still considered as string? I'll try the method you've recommended, thanks.

Comment: Anything delimited by `'` quotes is a string in Access SQL. There's very little automatic typecasting.

Comment: Thank you for your time & suggestion.