# MS-Access - SQL commands using boolean variables depending of language

Tags: ms-access, localization

On my workstation, I've been using Access in English. Some other computer that will use my form have it in French. Testing it recently, I found out that Boolean variable, even if declared as True/False, come out as Vrai/Faux.

Where it becomes a problem is when I need to use the variable in a text, like an insert or simply a request.

The only workaround I have right now is using another variable of type String and replace it from French to English. The problem with this is... it's two ugly line. I mean, there must be another way than having to that every time i might use a Boolean variable in a request?

EDIT: Here is two exemples.

```
SELECT [...] FROM [...] WHERE [...]  in (false , " & SomeBooleanValue & ");

-- OR --

str_Sql = "INSERT INTO [...]  VALUES ('" & form_Name & "', " & is_something & ")"

DoCmd.RunSQL str_Sql
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of when you'd use the variable in text please?  Usually, for example, I'd give my boolean field a name such as `HasQuit` and then write something like `WHERE HasQuit` and not worry about the `=TRUE` bit but I don't think you're using it that way....

Comment: What do you mean " ...Boolean variable, even if **declared** as True/False..." ?  A variable is declared as a data type, not a value.

Comment: you could use numbers interchangeably with `TRUE`/`FALSE`.   `True = -1`  `False = 0`

Comment: It's only in the user interface they are localised. In code (VBA), they will always be `True` and `False`, so it should present no issue for you.

Comment: @ashleedawg What i meant to say is when you assign a value to it. Like isNumeric = True , if you put a breakpoint right after it and check the value, it will be Vrai instead, on a French Access.

Comment: @Gustav The issue is in the code.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Edit incoming

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Added another exemple

Comment: The problem appears when you convert the variable to string, e.g. by concatenating. Example in German Access: `? "True is " & True` -> `True is Wahr`

Comment: @Andre It is exactly the problem.

Comment: I guess using parameters instead of SQL concatenation is the cleanest solution. Otherwise you could use `CInt()` to force it to numbers -1 and 0. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a direct solution to your issue. That said, consider Darren's extended code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use parameters with your two examples and then not worry about concatenating into your SQL string:

```
Sub Test_1()

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS SomeBooleanValue BIT; " & _
        "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field_2 = SomeBooleanValue")

    With qdf
        .Parameters("SomeBooleanValue") = True
        Set rst = .OpenRecordset
    End With

    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do
                Debug.Print .Fields("Field_1") & " - " & .Fields("Field_2")
                .MoveNext
            Loop While Not .EOF
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Test_2()

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS some_text TEXT(255), is_something BIT; " & _
        "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (some_text, is_something)")

    With qdf
        .Parameters("some_text") = "Some random text"
        .Parameters("is_something") = True
        .Execute
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format expression to force a `True/False` output string:

```
UKTrueFalse = Format(YourBooleanValue, "True;True;Fal\se")
```

As for your SQL, you could just use the numeric value:

```
SELECT [...] FROM [...] WHERE [...]  IN (0 , " & Str(Abs(SomeBooleanValue)) & ");
```

Comment: I'm guessing the format has 2 true because of the 3 state possibility of the checkbox? 
And what about the 'Fal\se' ?

Comment: No, it is for "positive;negative;zero" because VBA also counts positive values as True. In fact. only zero is False. The escaped _s_ is needed, or s will be read as _seconds_, thus a zero would be returned.