# Date data type Access 2013 - wrong results

Tags: ms-access

I have a problem with Access 2013.

I am doing a query to get the records that have dates smaller than the date included in a form. But, I'm getting wrong results. I don't know if that is an Access' issue or I'm doing something wrong.

```
Me.txtResultsForm.RowSource = " SELECT number FROM TBL_Course WHERE TBL_Course.finalDate <= #" & Format(Me.txtFinalDateForm, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "# "
```

I tried of this way too, but I get the same results:

```
Me.txtResultsForm.RowSource = " SELECT number FROM TBL_Course WHERE TBL_Course.finalDate <= #" & Me.txtFinalDateForm & "# "
```

Help!!!!!

Comment: You can make your question a bit easier to read by using the code tags. You can edit your question by clicking on "edit" button.

Comment: Stop concatenating SQL. Use parameterized queries instead, and let the database driver worry about formatting dates properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully agree with Ken's comment - see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49509616/7531598) from Erik von Asmuth for how to use parameterised queries.

---

As for your issue, you'll need to change:

```
Format(Me.txtFinalDateForm, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

to:

```
Format(Me.txtFinalDateForm, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```