# Data type miss match in criteria exxpression access

Tags: ms-access

I am going to VBA for deleting data table.

It shows the errors shown in the screenshot.

Please help me to resolve it.

```
Private Sub cmdxoa_Click()
    If Not (Me.frmformsub1.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.frmformsub1.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        If MsgBox("Do you wwant to delete ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE from db " & _
                " where NOLC = " & Me.frmformsub1.Form.Recordset.Fields("nolc")
            Me.frmformsub1.Form.Requery
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: theme css]
[image: errror here]

Comment: Please state the errors you are receiving

Comment: What datatype is the field `NOLC` in the table `db`?

Comment: NOLC in the table db is short text

Comment: @markaaronky I received notice:" Run-time eror 3464 - data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: **Moderator Note** Please don't edit your post to change your question completely. Ask a new question, if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

So if `NOLC` in the table is of type text, your criteria expression has to be:

```
"where NOLC = '" & Me.frmformsub1.Form.Recordset.Fields("nolc").Value & "'"
```

As you see you have to surround the value with `'`.

Remark: `.Value` isn't necessary, but it enhances the readability and assures that you are interested in the value and not in the object itself (the control in that case).

**BUT**: You should use parametrized queries instead string concatenation to avoid SQL injection:

[How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access)

Comment: Thanks ! It is working now. I have another question need to resolve. I edited my question in this. Please help me to resolve it. Thanks

Comment: This tears the context apart of my answer. You should undo your edit and open another question.