# Is there a way to pass parameters through an update query to a select query in Microsoft Access VBA using the execute command?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to use the Execute command in Access VBA code to run a saved update query (that changes some information in a select query) but I keep getting: "Runtime Error 3061 - Too few parameters, expected 3".

The update query has no criteria but the select query that it is editing does have a few criteria that are based on some TempVars.
Here is the first criteria the select query uses:

`Like IIf([TempVars]![VarAccessLevel] Between 3 And 4,"*",[TempVars]![VarLoginID])`

The second criteria used is:
`[TempVars]![VarClassBlockChosen]`

I'm assuming the TempVars are the 3 parameters it is looking for, but I have no clue how to go about providing them.

Here is the VBA code I have written.

`CurrentDb.Execute "qupdMarkAllAsPresent", dbFailOnError`

Notably, I started out with `Do.Cmd OpenQuery "qupdMarkAllAsPresent"` and it worked fine but after I attempted to switch to the Execute command (to prevent warning messages) it began asking for parameters.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49509616/7296893) provides an overview of all ways to pass parameters to queries. You should look at the _Using DAO_ section for the syntax, and will have to swap `CurrentDb.Execute` for using a QueryDef.

Comment: Are these coming from a Form?  If so it is [Forms]![TempVars]![VarAccessLevel] or sometimes you can just use Me![TempVars]![VarAccessLevel]

Comment: Set the TempVars