# Issue: error '3075' Syntax error (missing operator) access 2013

Tags: vba, ms-access

Can any of you please tell me what's wrong with my codes:

```
Private Sub Command379_Click

Dim strsearch as String

Dim strText as String

strText = Me.TxtSearch.Value

strsearch = "Select * from qryInfo 
where ((Supplier Name LIKE ""*" & strText & "*"") 
OR (Type LIKE ""*" & strText & "*""))"


Me.RecordSource = strsearch

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match text which include double quotation mark please follow here:

text:

```
"abc"
```

text in VBA:

```
"""" & "abc" & """" (4 double quotation marks are necessary)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Following should be considered:**

- If you have fieldnames with a blank inside like `Supplier Name` then you would have to surround it with square brackets: `[Supplier Name]`.
- The brackets `()` are not really necessary in your case. You can omit them.
- Instead of using two quotation marks (`""`), in order to add a literal quotation mark, you can use a single quote (`'`) instead, what makes it more clear to read.
- `Type` is a reserved word. If possible you shouldn't use it. Minimum would be to also surround it with square brackets (`[Type]`).
- If your SQL string really is splitted in several lines in VBA, then you would have to handle it explicitely by using underscores (`_`) and string concatenation:

  ```
  strTest = "This is a string" & _
            " defined in several" & _
            " lines of code in VBA."
  ```

  Alternatively you could use this:

  ```
  strTest = "This is a string"
  strTest = strTest & " defined in several"
  strTest = strTest & " lines of code in VBA."
  ```

**So finally your (single line) SQL containing VBA would be this:**

```
strSearch = "Select * From qryInfo Where [Supplier Name] Like '*" & strText & "*' Or [Type] Like '*" & strText & "*'"
```

**Important too:**

Be aware that your current approach, using string concatenation, doesn't avoid SQL injection, which is a real security problem!

Take a look here on how to handle it better (for example by using parameter queries in VBA): [How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access)

Answer (score 0):

Having nothing but wildcards is the same as having no WHERE criteria at all.  So you don't need a WHERE statement.

…...having said that - I would recommend you create the query using the Query Design View and then once it returns the records as you consider correct - then use the option to display it in SQL View.  This will give you the syntax.