# Variable in Dlookup in Access 2016 returns runtime error 13 - type mismatch

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

The logic isn't complex. The application uses a temporary table into which data for a report is appended. Once the report has been run, the data is cleared. Initially, the client told me that he would enter all the data (by taking attendance of people attending an event) would be done at once. Now, that has changed. I lookup the max ID in the temp table - if the number of rows is greater than 0. I then want to use dlookup to let the client know where she left off lest they create more problems.
Here's the logic:

```
Dim VMax As Variant
Dim VNFind As String
VMax = DMax("foodpantryid", "signin_sheet_data") 'This works correctly
MsgBox VMax 'This works correctly
VNFind = DLookup("last_name", "Dat_household_member", "[household_id]" = VMax) 'I get the type mismatch/error 13 here.
MsgBox VNFind 'so this never works
```

Additional information:

1. Household_id is a long integer. When I change it to integer, I get an error 94 (invalid use of null).
2. I have tried setting VMax to variant, integer, and long. Still no success. I would think variant would have worked.
3. The DLookup works if I don't include "[household_id]" = VMax.
4. I've tried including the =VMax in "" and that fails as well. That produces a 2471 error.

Comment: Is `Household_id` a `Large Number` in the table definition? If so, you would have to use a `LongLong` VBA variable, I would guess.

Answer (score 2):

You've put your `=` outside the string delimiters.

This means: say your ID is 5. Then the parameter is `"[household_id]" = 5`. That's a comparison between the string `"[household_id]"` and the number `5`, which causes a type mismatch, because you can't compare strings to numbers unless the string can be cast to a number.

Instead, you should include the `=` in your string, and the `DLookUp` should be:

```
DLookup("last_name", "Dat_household_member", "[household_id] = " & VMax)
```

Or, better yet, use [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/7296893). This avoids most typecasting and string concatenation errors.

```
TempVars!VMax = VMax
DLookup("last_name", "Dat_household_member", "[household_id] = TempVars!VMax")
TempVars.Remove "VMax"
```

Comment: Great, Eric! Didn't see that. :D

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.