# Select multiple values from one table1, find in table2 and insert in table3

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

There is table1 table2, table3.
In table1 need to select all column `Order_ID` values where column `Spec_ID` values = 1
Then, all selected `Order_ID`find in table2 `Order_ID` and copy all rows with that ID's to table3.

I know how to insert rows to other table, but I cant figure out how to select multiple values and use that multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an [INSERT INTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql) statement:

```
insert into table3
select * from table2 
where order_id in (select order_id from table1 where spec_id = 1)
```

This will work only if table2 and table3 have the exact number of columns with identical corresponding data types.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a job for VBA, but for an Append query.

Create a query that joins table1 and table2, has the criteria you need, and shows all columns you need to copy.

Then change the query to an Append query, and have it insert into table3.

If necessary, you can set the parameter(s) for the query with VBA, see [How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access)