# Checkbox Yes/No Change on Dropbox Change

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a Combo Box (`cbo1`) that list available Items. When I select an item in `cbo1`, I would like it change a checkbox to True (or Yes).

`cbo1` gets data from `tblLOG` where Box (checkbox) is NO Query

I've tried using

```
UPDATE tblLOG 
Set Box = True
WHERE Serial = cboSerial
```

Actual Code.

```
Private Sub cbo1_Change()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim Assm As String

    Assm = cbo1.Value

    'Exit this sub if the combo box is cleared
    Msg = "Make Update" & vbCr & vbCr

    i = MsgBox(Msg, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "UPDATE VALUE?")
    If i = vbYes Then
        strSQL = "UPDATE tblLOG " _
        & "SET Box= True " _
        & "WHERE Serial = Assm;"
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        Response = acDataErrAdded
    End If
End Sub
```

My Results are

> Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is because you are not evaluating your VBA variable `Assm`, but rather concatenating the string `"Assm"` to your SQL query.

```vb
strSQL = "UPDATE tblLOG " _
& "SET Box= True " _
& "WHERE Serial = Assm;"
```

If you were to `Debug.Print` the variable `strSQL` to the console, you would see the string:

```vb
"UPDATE tblLOG SET Box= True WHERE Serial = Assm;"
```

However, since `Assm` is not a string in the SQL query (i.e. it is not surrounded by single or double quotes), it is interpreted as a parameter whose value hasn't been supplied when the SQL query is subsequently executed.

---

To solve this, you could concatenate the evaluated value of the `Assm` variable, e.g.:

```vb
strSQL = "UPDATE tblLOG " _
& "SET Box= True " _
& "WHERE Serial = '" & Assm & "';"
```

This assumes that `Serial` is a **text** field - if this is not the case, remove the single quotes from the above.

Your entire code could be condensed somewhat to:

```vb
Private Sub cbo1_Change()
    If MsgBox("Make Update", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "UPDATE VALUE?") = vbYes Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "update tbllog set box = true where serial = '" & cbo1 & "';", dbFailOnError
        Response = acDataErrAdded
    End If
End Sub
```

Though, this is still open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and so a better practice is to [parameterise the query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/7531598), e.g.:

```vb
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "update tbllog t set t.box = true where t.serial = myserial;")
    .Parameters!myserial = cbo1
    .Execute
End With
```