# Writing to a database table from an Access form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to write to an editable database table, from an Access form, and I keep receiving a syntax error.

The table has about 30 columns, but I only want the record filling out 8 of them: (`Job #`, `Job Name`, `Date`, `Superintendent`, `Hauling Vendor`, `Material`, `LTC`, `Loads`).

The form consists of the 8 fields named the following:

- `ReportingCOM_Job`
- `ReportingBox_JobName`
- `ReportingBox_Date`
- `ReportingCom_SI`
- `ReportingCom_Vendor`
- `ReportingCom_Mat`
- `ReportingCom_LoadType`
- `ReportingBox_Loads`

These are a combination of drop down list from queries, text inputs, and hard coded values, so a simple *Open Form > New Record* will not work here; or so I do not believe.

Is this even even possible?

I am using the following line and can not get this error to clear.

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO MATLog(Job #, Job Name, Date, Superintendent, Hauling Vendor, Material, LTC, Loads) " & _
    " VALUES(" & Me.ReportingCOM_Job & "," & Me.ReportingCom_JobName & ",#" & Me.ReportingBox_Date & "#," & _
    Me.ReportingCom_SI & "," & Me.ReportingCom_Mat & "," & Me.ReportingCom_Vendor & "," & Me.ReportingCom_LoadType & ",#" & Me.ReportingBox_Loads & "#)"
```

This form should create a new record with these 8 fields, and leave the rest blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields with spaces or other [reserved names or symbols](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2) in their field names (such as `Date`) will need to be enclosed with square brackets, e.g.:

```sql
INSERT INTO MATLog([Job #], [Job Name] ... )
```

You will also need to surround the values of Text fields in the `VALUES` list with single or double quotes, e.g.:

```vb
",'" & Me.ReportingCom_JobName & "',
```

---

However, whilst the above should allow your query to execute successfully, your current approach of constructing a SQL statement using unvalidated form values input by a user is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/), and you will also encounter issues when inserting text values which themselves contain SQL string delimiters (single/double quotes).

Instead, a better approach is to [parameterise your query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/7531598).

One possible example of this could be the following:

```vb
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
    "insert into matlog ([Job #], [Job Name], [Date], Superintendent, [Hauling Vendor], Material, LTC, Loads) " & _
    "values (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8)")
    .Parameters!p1 = Me.ReportingCOM_Job
    .Parameters!p2 = Me.ReportingBox_JobName
    .Parameters!p3 = Me.ReportingBox_Date
    .Parameters!p4 = Me.ReportingCom_SI
    .Parameters!p5 = Me.ReportingCom_Vendor
    .Parameters!p6 = Me.ReportingCom_Mat
    .Parameters!p7 = Me.ReportingCom_LoadType
    .Parameters!p8 = Me.ReportingBox_Loads
    .Execute
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much @LeeMac This worked like a charm. And thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a saved query and open it to run. Doing so, you avoid any need to concatenate or punctuate.

**SQL** *(saved below as stored query, replace myFormName with actual form name)*

```sql
INSERT INTO MATLog([Job #], [Job Name], [Date], [Superintendent], 
                   [Hauling Vendor], [Material], [LTC], [Loads]) 
VALUES(Forms!myFormName!ReportingCOM_Job, Forms!myFormName!ReportingCom_JobName,
       Forms!myFormName!ReportingBox_Date, Forms!myFormName!ReportingCom_SI,
       Forms!myFormName!ReportingCom_Mat, Forms!myFormName!ReportingCom_Vendor, 
       Forms!myFormName!ReportingCom_LoadType, Forms!myFormName!ReportingBox_Loads)
```

**VBA** *(no need to close action queries, use warnings to avoid user prompts)*

```vb
'DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedQuery"
'DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```