# MS Access forms VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Single form where I am trying to get a message box to prompt the user when 2 fields from my form match what is in the table and other one doesn't match.

This is the code I have which is in a button on click event.

```
If Not IsNull(Me.L_dt) Then 
    If Me.Ref = DLookup("[Ref]", "tbl", "[Ref]='" & Forms!MyForm!Ref & "'") And _
        Me.Class = Nz(DLookup("[ClassTy]", "tbl", "[ClassTy]<>'" & Forms!MyForm!ClassTy & "'"), 0) And _
        Me.L_dt = DLookup("L_dt", "tbl", "L_dt= #" & Format(Forms!MyForm![L_dt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#") Then
            If MsgBox("This record has an existing Learn Dt for this Ref", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
                Cancel = True
                Me.Undo
                Exit Sub
            End If
    End If
End If
```

Expected Result should be if the Ref and L_Dt are the same but the Class is different then prompt user, if L_Dt, Ref and Class are all the same this is fine.

Currently this is not working as expected as getting prompt when all 3 match.

I think it's me.ClassTy line that is wrong but when I change the <> to = it still does not work.

Comment: *if the Ref and L_Dt are the same but the Class is different then prompt user, if L_Dt, Ref and Class are all the same this is fine.* So if the user inputs info that match with an existing record on fields `Ref ` and `L_Dt` but different `Class`, is wrong? that means your table only accepts records that match those 3 fields. Is that right?

Comment: `Class` is used in VBA and should not be used as field/control name. You can try `Me![Class]` but it still is a bad idea.

Comment: There are many fields within the table but for the example its the 3 fields,  I just need to make the user aware that they are using an unknown/Different Class where the other 2 fields match and let the user decide if they wish to continue.

Comment: Thanks I have renamed this now to ClassTy but still the same issue

Comment: Use [DCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.dcount) to count how many records match with the inputs of the user. If the count is 0, it means the user is creating a new record, but if the count is not 0, it means the `ClassTy` already exists (asiggned to that specific `Ref` and `L_Dt`).

Comment: Thanks Foxfire although I don't know how to do this in the above query as I'm not very good at vba. Can you show what me please. thanks

Comment: Never do `DLookup("L_dt", "tbl", "L_dt= #" & Format(Forms!MyForm![L_dt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")`! Always do `DLookup("L_dt", "tbl", "L_dt=Forms!MyForm![L_dt]")` instead. You're making your code more complicated and error-prone than necessary. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/7296893) on where form-based parameters are supported.

Comment: Are you writing this code to avoid dupes ? If so why not just create a unique index on the set of fields ? Much faster / safer / easier

Comment: Patrick, This is not to avoid duplicates but to notify the user that 2 of the same fields already exist in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Not IsNull(Me.L_dt) Then 
  If Me.Classty = Nz(DLookup("[ClassTy]", "tbl", "[ClassTy]='" & Forms!MyForm!ClassTy & "'"), 0) = false then
    If Me.Ref = DLookup("[Ref]", "tbl", "[Ref]='" & Forms!MyForm!Ref & "'") And _
        Me.L_dt = DLookup("L_dt", "tbl", "L_dt= Forms!MyForm![L_dt]") Then
            If MsgBox("This record has an existing Learn Dt for this Ref", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
                Cancel = True
                Me.Undo
                Exit Sub
            End If
     End if
  End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss a field name:

```
Format(Forms!MyForm![], ...
```

Comment: Sorry it is on my actual form but missed off of here, now updated. thanks