# Missing ' - SQL syntax issue in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to run SQL statment with variable in VB Access. I get error for syntax issue. I think I am missing ' or " in the statement, but I am not sure what to do.

Here is the code.

```
If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then 
   rs.MoveFirst


Do While rs.EOF = False
TempExportCount = TempExportCount + 1
Checkdatacsv = rs![FileName68]
OriginalFileName = rs![FileName]

'***
'This is the variable - batch number
'*** 

BatchNO = rs![BatchNumber] 

FullPath = DirectoryPath & Checkdatacsv




DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "AP-csv-Import", "tblAP_Payable_2", FullPath, False

Dim SQL2 As String

'***
'This is the statement
'*** 

SQL2 = "UPDATE tblAP_Payable_2 SET tblAP_Payable_2.BNO = " & BatchNO & "WHERE tblAP_Payable_2.BNO = 0;"


DoCmd.RunSQL SQL2

DoCmd.OpenQuery "qDEL_AP_BLank", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

When each line from csv files are imported, BatchNO is populated in the table so I will know each record is imported from which file

Comment: You need a space after the double-quotes at `"WHERE`.

Comment: From what you think could be that answer, I suspect that there is an apostrophe somewhere in the data so I recommend that you use SQL parameters for the values instead of putting them directly into the string with &. Please see [How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/1115360)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer :)

```
SQL2 = "UPDATE tblAP_Payable_2 SET tblAP_Payable_2.BNO = '" & BatchNO & "WHERE tblAP_Payable_2.BNO = 0;'"
```

Comment: This won't throw an error, but won't do what you want - it will overwrite the whole column. [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Comment: This is missing the `'` after the BatchNo as shown in @Gustavs answer: `'" & BatchNO & "' WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, *BatchNo* is text, thus needs quotes and - as already noted - you miss a space:

```
SQL2 = "UPDATE tblAP_Payable_2 SET tblAP_Payable_2.BNO = '" & BatchNO & "' WHERE tblAP_Payable_2.BNO = 0;"
```