# Is my query and use of apostrophes right?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Trying to get this query right where it takes in variables to update the records. I tried playing around with the quotation marks and either I would get "Enter a parameter value" dialogue screen or "Syntax error (Missing Operator)" error.

```
updateOriginalBudget_SQL = "UPDATE SubPhases SET OriginalBudget=" & matchBudget & " " & "WHERE ShopCode=" & elemShopCode & ";"
DoCmd.RunSQL updateOriginalBudget_SQL
```

matchBudget is an integer and elemShopCode is a String. If I just  write a simple query like:

```
"UPDATE SubPhases SET OriginalBudget=5 WHERE ShopCode='344S-23';"
```

it'll work with no issues. 
Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you use parameters, you won't get this issue, and you avoid the risk of SQL injection. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/7296893) for how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original query, you're missing the quotes `''` for field values. In your `ShopCode` you have a value with `-` which is an operator and that's why you're getting a `"Syntax error (Missing Operator)"` error.

Change the query like this and it will work:

```
updateOriginalBudget_SQL = "UPDATE SubPhases SET OriginalBudget=" & matchBudget & " WHERE ShopCode='" & elemShopCode & "';"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You had quoted the number.

Comment: @Louis Oh I know now what I was doing wrong. This solved my issue.