# Access query doesn't run on workbook close

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to run an Access delete query when I close my Excel workbook.  I want the DELETE query to delete any record that is prior to today's date in the "ResDate" field.  Below is the code I have written.  The workbook closes but the records remain in the database (TR table).

I thought this would work but am striking out so far.  Any suggestions on getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help...…….

```
Const ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=H:\MyDatabase\TRC.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
    Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
    Connection.Open

    VSQL = "DELETE * FROM [TR] WHERE [TR].ResDate < " & Date

    Set RecSet1 = Connection.Execute(VSQL, dbrows, adCmdText)

    Connection.Close

    Set RecSet1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @HansUp...….I use the Immediate window and the sql looks like this:  DELETE * FROM [TrainingRoom] WHERE [TrainingRoom].ResDate < 11/8/2019

Comment: Access SQL interprets `11/8/2019` as 11 divided by 8 divided by 2019.  If you want it interpreted as a date instead, include `#` delimiters like this ... `#11/8/2019#`  But if your intention is the date will always be today's date, just use the `Date()` function --- no delimiters or formatting issues to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Access `Date()` function in your SQL statement, instead of inserting the date as text into the statement.

Include `Option Explicit` in your module's Declarations section and run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  Fix the first compile error Access complains about, and then Debug->Compile again.  Repeat until no more errors.

Opening a recordset based on a `DELETE` query is not useful because a `DELETE` does not return records.  Simply execute your query instead.

```vb
Const ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=H:\MyDatabase\TRC.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim VSQL As String
    Dim dbrows As Long
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
    cn.Open

    VSQL = "DELETE * FROM [TR] WHERE [TR].ResDate < Date()"

    cn.Execute VSQL, dbrows, adCmdText

    cn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: ...……...Thanks for your time today.  this worked just like I was expecting it to.  It deletes the old records (prior to today) just like I needed it to.  Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

ALWAYS USE PARAMETERS!

When you do `VSQL = "DELETE * FROM [TR] WHERE [TR].ResDate < " & Date`, depending on your locale, that can result in several issues.

For example, `DELETE * FROM [TR] WHERE [TR].ResDate < 2019-11-08`, and 2019 minus 11 minus 08 is equal to 2000 and `CDate(2000)` is 1905-06-22, so this is a valid query, but probably won't delete what you want to delete.

In an alternate locale, it might be 11/08/2019, and 11 divided by 8 divided by 2019 is approximately 0 and `CDATE(0)` is 1899-12-30.

Instead, pick and choose from [How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/7296893), for example:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
    Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
    Connection.Open

    VSQL = "DELETE * FROM [TR] WHERE [TR].ResDate < " & Date
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
         Set .ActiveConnection = Connection
         .CommandText = "DELETE * FROM [TR] WHERE [TR].ResDate < ?"
         Set RecSet1 = .Execute(, Array(Date))
    End With
    Connection.Close

    Set RecSet1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: ...….thanks for your help and the information provided.  This has a limited release so I don't have to worry about locale but I learned something with your answer....