# Access VBA Docmd.OpenQuery Can Run an update query but Currentdb.Excecute Cannot

Tags: vba, ms-access, updates, dao

I created a saved update query as below, which has control values and `IIf` function.

```
UPDATE SYS_AAAA_AAAH 
SET SYS_AAAA_AAAH.AAK = AAA & " " & AAB & IIf(IsNull(AAC),"","(" & AAC & ")") & IIf(IsNull(AAF),""," not null") & " comment '" & AAH & "',"
WHERE (((SYS_AAAA_AAAH.AAO)=[forms]![frmAdmiTabl]![CombSAAO]));
```

`DoCmd.OpenQuery` can run it while `Currentdb.Execute` gives an error message 'too few parameters'. I created another saved update query without input from control or function and Currentdb.Execute worked. I don't want to see the warning message from `Docmd.OpenQuery` and I dont want to mess around by turning on and off the warning. Anyway of getting `Currentdb.Execute` work on this?

Comment: They behave differently: [How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access)

Comment: It is good to know this but it did not really pointing the direction of a solution to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to update a column of some certain records with another column's value and `IIf` function, it is better to use `DAO.recordset` `edit` and `update`

```
  Dim Rs_AAAH As DAO.Recordset

    Set Rs_AAAH = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from Table where AAO='" & Me.CombSAAO.Value & "'", dbOpenDynaset)

    Rs_AAAH.MoveFirst

    Do Until Rs_AAAH.EOF

        With Rs_AAAH
            .Edit
            .Fields("AAK").Value = Rs_AAAH.Fields("AAA") & " " & Rs_AAAH.Fields("AAB") & IIf(IsNull(Rs_AAAH.Fields("AAC")), "", "(" & Rs_AAAH.Fields("AAC") & ")") & IIf(IsNull(Rs_AAAH.Fields("AAF")), "", " not null") & " comment '" & Rs_AAAH.Fields("AAH") & "',"
            .Update
        End With

        Rs_AAAH.MoveNext
    Loop

    Rs_AAAH.Close
    Set Rs_AAAH = Nothing
```