# Which operator is incorrect and returns error '3075'?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I've encounter run time error '3075', not sure what went wrong. Please help.

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()

If Me.cobDepartment <> "" Then


     CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblSite " & _
     " SET DepartmentID= " & Me.cobDepartment & _
     " WHERE Payroll number=" & Me.Payroll_number.Value & ""
     MsgBox "Updated"

     Else
     MsgBox "Select Department"



End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I Think "Payroll number" must be in brackets, like this: [Payroll number].

Comment: Didn't work error 3464 - data type mismatch

Comment: Semi colon is missing at the end of the query  - Me.Payroll_number.Value & ";". And check if the payroll_number.value's data type is same as the data type of Payroll number column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. Since `cobDepartment` appears to be a string (given that you have the expression `Me.cobDepartment <> ""` earlier in the code), the value will need to be surrounded by single or double quotes within the SQL statement, e.g.:

   ```
   "SET DepartmentID='" & Me.cobDepartment & "'"
   ```
2. Fields containing spaces or which correspond to reserved words in MS Access will need to be enclosed within square brackets, e.g.:

   ```
   [Payroll number]
   ```
3. **Most importantly:** concatenating values directly into a SQL statement exposes your code to the possibility of [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/), whereby a user could 'inject' additional SQL instructions into the values being concatenated.

   A far better approach would be to use parameters, e.g.:

   ```
   Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()
       If Me.cobDepartment <> "" Then
           With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("","update tblsite set departmentid=@did where [payroll number]=@prn")
               .Parameters("@did") = Me.cobDepartment
               .Parameters("@prn") = Me.Payroll_number
               .Execute
           End With
           MsgBox "Updated"
       Else
           MsgBox "Select Department"
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

   The use of parameters in this way has the additional benefit of automatically handling the varying SQL data types within your SQL statement, avoiding the need for additional quotes or formatting of values.

   Of course, this is just one possible way to use parameters within a SQL statement in MS Access - [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49509616/7531598) describes many other methods.