# Date filter returns an invalid character error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, adodb

I want to execute a query with a date filter in Access VBA.

My first issue was inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER.
I assume Access stores dates as numbers just like Excel.
I found I had to use "#" between the date for the query to recognize it as a DATE. Now I am getting an INVALID CHARACTER error which means the hash # is an invalid character.

I have to pull in the negotiated costs with our vendors that don't have more than 60 days of being expired.
There is also a tblVendors where the user selects the vendor ID (ORDID) they want to pull the info from. That's why I do a loop to pull in every ORDID in that table. I don't push in all the ORDID in one try because it brings a lot of data and doing it in batches runs faster.

```vb
Sub GetMaterialCost()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset, rsVendor As DAO.Recordset, rsItemCost As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim vendorNO As Long, dtDate As Date
        
    Set db = CurrentDb
    dtDate = Format(Now() - 60, "m/d/yyyy")
    Set rsVendor = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ORDID, VEN_NAME, USER_ID FROM tblVendors WHERE ACTIVE = TRUE ORDER BY VEN_NAME, ORDID")
    Set rsItemCost = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_ItemCost")
          
    ConnectBILL
        
    rsVendor.MoveFirst
    Do Until rsVendor.EOF
            
        strQuery = "SELECT MASID, LOCATION, ITEM, ITEM_QTY, ITEM_UOM, ITEM_COST, EXP_DT " _
          & "FROM ITEMMASTER INNER JOIN ORDDETAIL ON (ITEMMASTER.ITEM = ORDDETAIL.ITEM) " _
          & "WHERE (LOCATION IN (AS1,AS3,AS6) AND TRIM(MASID)  = '" & Cstr(rsVendor.Fields("ORDID")) & "' AND EXP_DT >= @paramDate)"
            
        With ComBill
            .CommandText = strQuery
            Set rsData = .Execute(, Array(dtDate))
        end with    
                   
        'clears previous instance of vendor data by vendor_no if it exists
        db.Execute "DELETE * FROM tbl_ItemCost WHERE MASID LIKE '*" & rsVendor.Fields("ORDID") & "*'"
    
        'starts inserting queried data
        rsData.MoveFirst
        Do Until rsData.EOF
      
            With rsItemCost
                .AddNew
                    
                .Fields("MASID") = rsData!MASID
                .Fields("LOCATION") = rsData!LOCATION
                .Fields("ITEM") = rsData!ITEM
                .Fields("ITEM_UOM") = Trim(rsData!ITEM_UOM)
                .Fields("ITEM_COST") = rsData!ITEM_COST
                .Fields("EXP_DT") = rsData!EXP_DT
                    
                .Update
            End With
                
            rsData.MoveNext
        Loop
          
        rsVendor.MoveNext
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing an `&` here: `TRIM(MASID)  = '" Cstr(`. Also, [use parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/7296893). It would've avoided this error while simultaneously making working with dates in different locales a lot easier and avoiding SQL injection.

Comment: The closing paren here does not have a matching open paren: `#" & dtDate & "#) "`.  It looks like there is an orphan open paren here `& Cstr(rsVendor.Fields("ORDID") &`.  Move the `"` at the very end of that line to before the `)`.

Comment: @ErikA I edited my question and fixed those errors you pointed out. I will also look into parameters, it looks like that will save me a lot of troubles in the future. For know, even after fixing those mistakes the invalid character error persists.

Comment: @knot22, fixed and tried again but the problem persists

Comment: @ErikA, I tried using ADO parameters. But I gives a missing expression when executing `EXP_DT >= @paramDate`   `Set rsData = .Execute(, dtDate)`

Comment: It's expecting an array there, so try passing a single-element array: `Set rsData = .Execute(, array(dtDate))`. Note that for full parameterization, you'd use parameters both for the ORDID field and the date one.

Comment: @ErikA, still shows missing expression. I tried to execute without filtering by date, just to see if the query itself had an error, but it executed successfully.

Comment: Could you edit in the full attempt? The error is likely outside the small fragment you shared

Comment: @ErikA , I edited it!

Comment: Try the following (using a connection instead of a command is hacky, I tend to avoid it): `With CreateObject("ADODB.Command") |  .ActiveConnection  = ComBill
            .CommandText = strQuery | 
            Set rsData = .Execute(, Array(dtDate)) | 
        end with`  (replace | with enter). I can't spot any real errors though...

Comment: @ErikA I fixed. Instead of `@paramDate` I used `?` and it executed. Why do you think? I liked to used named parameters, it would make them easier to read for the future me

Comment: That shouldn't really matter if you use Access as a backend, so I don't have a clue, sorry. If you're inserting into another type of database, that changes the rules substantially.

Comment: Yeah, ithe database is in oracle. Thanks tho, I learned something really nice about parameters

Answer (score 0):

Correct these two lines:

```
dtDate = DateAdd("d", -60, Date)
    
             & "WHERE LOCATION IN (AS1,AS3,AS6) AND TRIM(MASID)  = '" & CStr(rsVendor.Fields("ORDID") & "' AND EXP_DT >= #" & Format(dtDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) "
```

Note, that for ADO, string expressions for date values *must* be formatted using the ISO sequence.

If the field `EXP_DT` is Text:

```
             & "WHERE LOCATION IN (AS1,AS3,AS6) AND TRIM(MASID)  = '" & CStr(rsVendor.Fields("ORDID") & "' AND EXP_DT >= '" & Format(dtDate, "m\/d\/yyyy") & "') "
```

Comment: `AND EXP_DT >= #2020/07/05#` gives the same invalid character error. I changed the other things you said. The EXP_DT column has dates as 'm/d/yyyy'.

Comment: A DateTime value carries no format; formatting is to create a string expression for the value in SQL. Perhaps the field is Text. Either change that (dates should always be stored as DateTime) or adopt. See extended answer, please.