# MS Access: Inserting value from current record into another table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, insert

I have a button that should take the "address" field from the current record, and add it to the TAddressCorrectionExclusions table, which consists of just ID (autonumber) and Address. However when I run the below code, it prompts for a value for tempaddress. How do I store the current record's 'address' field as tempaddress?

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim TempAddress As String
TempAddress = Me.Address ' This is the part that's not working
SQL = "INSERT INTO TAddressCorrectionExclusions (Address) VALUES (TempAddress)"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Comment: Concatenate variable input. `INSERT INTO TAddressCorrectionExclusions(Address) VALUES('" & TempAddress & "')"`. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access

Comment: That's it, thank you! Now I just need to figure out why that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `TempAddress` is not a named field in any referenced context, the query engine prompts you for such a value (which is really an error if not using MS Access GUI). Notice how you use `TempAddress` like other identifiers: `TAddressCorrectionExclusions` and `Address`.

Remember SQL is a *separate* process from VBA and does not know anything about its application layer. This includes SQL with other application layers: Java, Python, PHP, C#, etc.

```sql
INSERT INTO TAddressCorrectionExclusions (Address) VALUES (TempAddress)
```

What you really intended to do is pass the underlying value of VBA variable, *TempAddress*, into SQL query. Therefore, the usual answer is to concatenate the VBA variables into SQL query, wrapping string values in quotes.

```vb
SQL = "INSERT INTO TAddressCorrectionExclusions (Address) VALUES ('" & TempAddress & "')"
```

---

However, an even better solution is to use the form control directly in a stored query that recognizes the value as a parameter if form is opened. This effectively separates SQL from VBA for readability and maintainability.

**SQL** *(save as a stored Access query; adjust 'myform' name)*

```sql
INSERT INTO TAddressCorrectionExclusions (Address) VALUES (Forms!myform!Address)
```

**VBA** *(single one-line command; action queries do not need to be closed)*

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedAppendQuery"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is super helpful!