# Openrecordset too few parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters

I have a VBA project that runs into an error:

```
Dim db
Dim rstOrders As Recordset
Dim rstTabOrders As Recordset
Dim strOrders As String

Set db = CurrentDb
strOrders = "SELECT SQY_ImportOrders_Basis.[Nummer inkooporder] FROM SQY_ImportOrders_Basis"
Set rstTabOrders = db.OpenRecordset("Tab_InkoopOrders", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rstOrders = db.OpenRecordset(strOrders, dbOpenDynaset)
```

This code hangs on the last line (Set rstOrders =...) ginving an error saying that there are too few parameters and it expects 1.

Furthermore: the strOrders query, works fine when pasted in an SQL query.

The query "SQY_ImporOrders.Basis" has a part of a field that is linked tot a form. The form is open as the code is started y a button on that form.
The reference to the form is in a part a of a query field:
[image: criteria of that field]
[image: Field]

I can't seem tot find where this goes wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but I would assume you need a space before the `FROM` in your SQL statement.

Comment: you really got me confused with your variable names `rstOrders` and `strOrders`

Comment: I corrected the code: added a space before FROM. Problem not solved and still the same...

Comment: is there any parameter in `SQY_ImportOrders_Basis`? any criteria?

Comment: yes. in that query is a criterium to a form field...

Comment: That's it. You must pass that parameter value.

Comment: I didn't have enough information to replicate the problem, but have you tried running the query when that form is open vs that form is closed.  If query works when the form is open then wrap the form field in a public get function and decide what value it will have when the form is closed.

Comment: the form is open. i added this info just now to the problem description

Comment: It doesn't matter. `db.OpenRecordset` cannot evaluate this parameter. As explained in the linked duplicate.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access

Comment: What kind of form is this? And could you maybe set a breakpoint before the last line of code, and then set a watch for strOrders? If I were you, I would like to see what the actual SQL statement that is executed looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a typo in the select statement you would get this error. Try `SELECT * FROM SQY_ImportOrders_Basis`.

Comment: Same problem persists...