# Getting error for too few parameters in SQL string in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a SQL string in a set of code in VBA for Access. The code is:

```
Private Sub Command40_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
    

    strSQL = "Delete * From TEMP_AssignSequence"
    
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    db.Execute strSQL

    Call ResetSeed("TEMP_AssignSequence")
    
    strSQL = "PARAMETERS [Forms]![JobQuote]![JobID] Short;"
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO TEMP_AssignSequence ( CaptionText )"
    strSQL = strSQL & " SELECT tblContractors.Contractor"
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM tblContractors INNER JOIN tblContractorJob ON tblContractors.ContractorID = tblContractorJob.ContractorID"
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (((tblContractorJob.JobID)=[Forms]![JobQuote]![JobID]))"
    strSQL = strSQL & " GROUP BY tblContractors.Contractor"
    strSQL = strSQL & " Order By tblContractors.Contractor;"

    db.Execute strSQL



End Sub
```

When I build the query in the design window, it outputs the same exact string. However, when I try to run this code, I get the error `3061: Too few parameters. Expected 1`

I am a little confused since this runs perfectly when in a query, but wont run via VBA as a string. I assume I am handling my WHERE incorrectly as far as VBA is concerned?

Comment: This line here is overwritten by the next line -     `strSQL = "PARAMETERS [Forms]![JobQuote]![JobID] Short;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing through DAO, which does not support form-based parameters. If you want to use form-based parameters, you can only execute through `DoCmd.RunSQL`:

```vb
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Alternately, you could use a querydef to add parameters.

See [How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access) for more on which parameters are supported in which context.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Would I just set strSQL as a normal string, then execute via docmd rather then db.execute?

Comment: I'd never do that, but my databases all contain a small function that takes an SQL string and parameters as a paramarray, then executes that SQL string using the given parameters, so I tend to use that.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you need to concatenate:

```vb
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TEMP_AssignSequence ( CaptionText )"
    strSQL = strSQL & " SELECT tblContractors.Contractor"
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM tblContractors INNER JOIN tblContractorJob ON tblContractors.ContractorID = tblContractorJob.ContractorID"
    strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE (((tblContractorJob.JobID)=" & [Forms]![JobQuote]![JobID] & "))"
```

Comment: I tried making that change and get a syntax error ```Expected: End of statement```. I am not well versed in SQL, so I always use the wizards to build it for me, so I have a rough time when it comes to correcting such errors.

Comment: It was a string error, not SQL. This is air code, of course.