# ms access vba "Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 7" when querying access query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I google a lot and read all post here related to this issue but found nothing that could give an explanation or help me to resolve this issue.
Following here, a function which work great when the "TableName" parameter is a base table but raise error when it is an ms access view (query). I found nothing yet that could explain this issue as many access query already refer to such views (queries) without issues.

```
Function DBDistinctCount(FieldName As String, tableName As String) As Long
Dim rs As Recordset, curDb As Database, strSql As String

    On Error GoTo ERR_Handling
    Set curDb = CurrentDb
    'strSql = "SELECT COUNT(PR.[" & FieldName & "]) AS CNT FROM (SELECT [" & FieldName & "] FROM " & TableName & " GROUP BY [" & FieldName & "]) AS PR;"
    strSql = "SELECT COUNT(PR." & FieldName & ") AS CNT FROM (SELECT " & FieldName & " FROM " & tableName & " GROUP BY " & FieldName & ") AS PR;"
    'strSql = "SELECT COUNT([" & FieldName & "]) AS CNT FROM (SELECT [" & FieldName & "] FROM [" & TableName & "] GROUP BY [" & FieldName & "]);"
    
    'Debug.Print result: SELECT COUNT(PR.ID_Projet) AS CNT FROM (SELECT ID_Projet FROM R_CompilationProjet GROUP BY ID_Projet) AS PR
    
'    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
'    Set qdf = curDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSql)
    
    Set rs = curDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
'    Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
    
    DBDistinctCount = Nz(rs.Fields("CNT"), 0)
    
ERR_Handling:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Dim mess As String
        mess = "Erreur vba " & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
        On Error Resume Next
        Call DBHelper.AddLog(mess, "DBDistinctCount")
    End If
    
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    
    If Not curDb Is Nothing Then curDb.Close
    Set curDb= Nothing
    
End Function
```

As you can see, I messed up the function a bit in order to find out what could be wrong. I even tried to use a querydef with the same result. I should mention that I've tried to put the resulting sql string itself inside an access query to see exactly the expected result when I ran the query. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most probably: your base query `R_CompilationProjet` refers to **form controls** for parameters. This doesn't work with DB.OpenRecordset, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access

Comment: You're right @Andre. I had a closer look to that query to see that it was using form parameters. I will have to find an alternative to that annoying issue. Thank you very much to bright my light.

Comment: I've written a small Q&A for how to open recordsets using form-based parameters or UDFs, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66414147/7296893). This could save you from having to fill in all those form parameters the query relies on manually, but is a bit hacky, so I'd probably manually fill in those parameters anyway if the query will not change.