# Ensure Unique Records in Form (MS Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms, dlookup

Using a Form in MS Access, I need to ensure only unique records are entered into the table.

It's unfortunately in a situation where I can't enforce unique records via the table's primary keys.

I have the following code in the BeforeUpdate for the Form, but it is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If DCount("*", "[Role_Details]", "[Role] = " & Me.[ComboRole] & " AND [Session] = " & Me.[ComboSession]) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Duplicate!"
    Cancel = True
    Me.[ComboSession].SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Note: The table name is "Role_Details". Field names are "Role" and "Session". With "ComboRole" and "ComboSession" being the Form Field Labels.

Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong here?

### Updates##

When I open the DataSheet Form, it presents a popup box saying "Enter Parameter Value" and "frm_Role_Details.Session". I'm not sure why this is, but I can enter past it and open the Form.

Then, them i'm entering a record an error pops up saying "Run-time error '2465': Can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression. Both Fields are Text Strings. I'm at a loss!

Comment: What's not working?  It's just not producing the result you expect, or the code itself produces an error?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with not escaping values properly. Review [How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/7296893) to avoid these.

Comment: What data type are the combo outputs?  are they numeric or string type?  Do you need parenthesis?  This may also help and trap errors? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/prevent-duplicate-values-in-a-table-field-using-an-index-b5eaace7-6161-4edc-bb90-39d1a1bc5576

Comment: When I open the DataSheet Form, it presents a popup box saying "Enter Parameter Value" and "frm_Role_Details.Session". I'm not sure why this is, but I can enter past it and open the Form.

Then, them i'm entering a record an error pops up saying "Run-time error '2465': Can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression.

Both Fields are Text Strings.

I'm at a loss on both points mentioned above.

Comment: What do you mean by "being the Form Field Labels"? Are these Names for comboboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When concatenating in VBA, text fields require apostrophe delimiters for inputs.

```
If DCount("*", "[Role_Details]", "[Role] = '" & Me.[ComboRole] & "' AND [Session] = '" & Me.[ComboSession] & "'")> 0 Then
```

Date/Time fields use `#` delimiter.

Number fields do not use any delimiter.

Comment: Worked like a charm @June7, thank you so much!!