# Trying to update table in ms Access using VBA but getting failed , used multiple option but table not getting updated

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Trying to update table in ms Access using VBA but getting failed , used multiple option but table not getting updated

```
Dim bod As Date
Dim assets As String
Dim emname As String
Dim ecode As String
Dim Astatus As String
      
Astatus = "SOLD"    
        
msaved = True
DoCmd.SetWarnings False            
bod = Me.datetime.Caption
price1k = Me.cmbox1_1AID.Value
emname = Me.empname.Value
ecod = Nz(Me.code.Value, 0)
        
//tried using this but not getting updated no error
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Asset E7450 List] SET Code = '" & ecod & "',[Date & Time] ='" & bod & "' ,Status ='" & Astatus & "',[Sold To] ='" & empname & "', where Asset-ID ='" & price1k & "'"
      
// Tried using this no update no error 
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Asset E7450 List] SET Code = '" & ecod & "',[Date & Time] ='" & bod & "' ,Status ='" & Astatus & "',[Sold To] ='" & empname & "', where Asset-ID ='" & price1k & "'"
    
// Tried this method no data update no error
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE [Asset E7450 List] SET Code = '" & ecod & "',[Date & Time] ='" & bod & "' ,Status ='" & Astatus & "',[Sold To] ='" & empname & "', where Asset-ID ='" & price1k & "'"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
         
MsgBox " Booking Request Accepted ", vbInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [Date & Time] is a date/time type field, use `#` delimiter instead of `'`. If field is a number type, don't use any delimiter.

Remove the comma in front of WHERE clause.

Need `[ ]` around Asset-ID field name because of the hyphen.

Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for the respond .. i changed here plz let me know if its correct .. actually still its not getting save ..  strSQL = "UPDATE [Asset E7450 List] SET Code = '" & ecod & "',[Date & Time] =#" & bod & "# ,Status ='" & Astatus & "',[Sold To] ='" & empname & "', where [Asset-ID] =" & price1k & ""

Comment: Still have a comma in front of WHERE. Asset-ID is a text field?

Comment: i removed that but still not getting updated

Comment: Don't see anything else wrong with concatenated string. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access

Comment: strSQL = "UPDATE [Asset E7450 List] SET Code = '" & ecod & "',[Date & Time] =#" & bod & "# ,Status ='" & Astatus & "',[Sold To] ='" & empname & "', where [Asset-ID] =" & price1k & ""
 DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
 
 MsgBox " Booking Request Accepted ", vbInformation
Me.subform.Requery
Me.code.Enabled = False
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Comment: Could use CurrentDb.Execute and don't have to deal with warnings. `Debug.Print strSQL` to see the constructed string in Immediate Window then copy/paste it into query object to test. You are still showing a comma in front of WHERE.

Comment: tried changing , CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Asset E7450 List] SET Code = '" & ecod & "',[Date & Time] =#" & bod & "# ,Status ='" & Astatus & "',[Sold To] ='" & empname & ", where [Asset-ID] =" & price1k & ""       if i do debug.print do not get any output

Comment: Why do you not understand? Again, there is a comma in front of WHERE, remove it. `& ", where` should be `& " where`.

Comment: would request your assistance, let me know how can i share you all the details so you can help me to find why this is not getting update .. please

Comment: You could post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis. Fix the comma as instructed. I can see nothing else wrong with SQL.

Comment: CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Asset E7450 List] SET Code = '" & ecod & "',[Date & Time] =#" & bod & "# ,Status ='" & Astatus & "',[Sold To] ='" & empname & "' where [Asset-ID] =" & price1k & ""

Comment: when i used debug.print strSQL this is the response ...
UPDATE [Asset E7450 List] SET Code = 'AO526',[Date & Time] =#31-08-2021 12:26:24 AM# ,Status ='SOLD',[Sold To] ='AKASH JAIN where [Asset-ID] =MGS-BLR-L003

Comment: it shows correct data but not getting updated in table

Comment: Well, that output shows missing apostrophe delimiters for `[Sold To] ='AKASH JAIN where [Asset-ID] =MGS-BLR-L003`. Your latest version of SQL code does not have them.

Comment: Thank you  so much for the assistance .. finally its updating the Table . Thank you lot again ... may i know your good name & location.

Comment: Name is June in Alaska. If answer resolved issue, please mark it accepted.

Comment: please help me with this Dim dupsql

dupsql = "SELECT * FROM [BookingTable]WHERE Code = ='" & ecode & "'"
DoCmd.FindRecord dupsql, , True, , True

MsgBox " The Entered Code is already in Use! ", vbInformation

Comment: would like to validate if data is available in table so it should confirm

Comment: Could use DLookup instead of opening a recordset. This is a new issue and should start a new question.

Comment: yes i have posted in new quest .. request your assistance