# SQL SELECT QUERY with WHERE AND doesn't work

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, where-clause

This shows records

```
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE DateOfHoliday >= #" & d1 & "#"
```

this doesn't

```
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE DateOfHoliday >= #" & d1 & "# AND DateOfHoliday <= #" & d2 & "#"
```

`d1` and  `d2` are datetimes, the format of `DateOfHoliday` and `d1` and `d2` is the same (MM/DD/YYYY)

for example

```
Dim d1 As Date
d1 = #9/15/2021#
Dim d2 As Date
d2 = #11/29/2021#
```

One of the `DateOfHoliday` is 9/28/2021
and the `Debug.Print strSQL` returns :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE DateOfHoliday >= #9/15/2021# AND DateOfHoliday <= #11/29/2021#
```

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data and desired output as text tables. Are your dates in U.S. structure (MM/DD/YYYY)?

Comment: Try to use `OR` instead of `AND` in `WHERE` Clause

Comment: yes they are in U.S. structure

Comment: You could try to use `BETWEEN` instead.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_between_date&ss=-1

Comment: give concrete examples of values for `d1` and `d2`. Make sure `d1` is the older date of those 2 values.

Comment: Use a `Debug.Print strSQL` on the next line to see what the complete SQL statement looks like.

Comment: Cant really help without seeing the records

Comment: If you want records where DateOfHoliday is between d1 and d2, try BETWEEN AND: `WHERE DateOfHoliday BETWEEN #" & d1 & "# AND #" & d2 & "#"`. However, what you tried should produce the same output.

Comment: Never use string concatenation with dates since how this is handled depends on computer locale settings. Use parameters instead: [How do I use parameters in VBA in the different contexts in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49509616/7296893)

Comment: Do you really have any record smaller than 11/29/2021 ?

Comment: I have edited the question with some info you asked

Comment: I still think it is a date structure problem maybe

Comment: Code works for me with either syntax.

Comment: See [Examples of using dates as criteria in Access queries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762) at section *"Contain values within a date range (between two dates)"*. Your code should work as long as `DateOfHoliday` field has a date format (can you verify?). Can you ensure that you have dates in your database between those 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query with each condition in ( )

```
"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (DateOfHoliday >= #" & d1 & "#) AND (DateOfHoliday <= #" & d2 & "#)"
```

Comment: Those parentheses will not change behavior. The criteria should work without them. Something else is issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, *Date* values carry no format. Next, most likely, your date field is *Text*. Try:

```vb
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE DateValue(DateOfHoliday) >= #" & d1 & "# AND DateValue(DateOfHoliday) <= #" & d2 & "#"
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer that this is most likely a datatype problem. Alternatively to the code suggested in the previous answer you may try:

```
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE CDate(DateOfHoliday) >= Cdate(#" & d1 & "#) AND CDate(DateOfHoliday) <= CDate(#" & d2 & "#)"
```

If this still fails, I suggest you try the following workaround:

```
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE DateOfHoliday >= #" & d1 & "#) WHERE DateOfHoliday <= #" & d2 & "#)"
```

More information in [LightningGuide.net](https://LightningGuide.net).