# How to Pass a parameter into the microsoft access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, parameters

hello i have a query in ms access called AddNewProject that will insert a new row in a table is simply says :

```
insert into Projects ([ProjectName]) values (@projectName)
```

now my problem is : I need to execute this query and pass the parameter when I am executing it , I have tried this code : `select AddNewProject as @projectName='FirstProject`
but that did not work. can you developers please help me with this

Comment: If you want this in a query object, Parameter must be either a user response to a popup input prompt or reference to a control on a form. Fairly certain `@projectName` means nothing in Access. Review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-declaration-microsoft-access-sql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509615/how-do-i-use-parameters-in-vba-in-the-different-contexts-in-microsoft-access

Comment: Why don't you just use a bound form for data entry?

Comment: When you say 'need to execute this query', do you mean when you double-click or open it, or call it from VBA, or use it as a datasource in a form or report; please elaborate. @projectname does not indicate a parameter in MsAccess; unless you are using ADODB library and run this as a query text (not MsAccess saved query).

Answer (score 1):

Salam Ali,

Let's assume:

1. You call it from VBA.
2. There is a table named "Projects" and it has field "ProjectName".

You can put this code on particular form module or on standard module.
Here i put this code on standard module.

```
Public Function addNewProject(strProjectName As String) As Boolean
    Dim cSQL As String, cParam As String
    Dim tableName As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim cQDf As DAO.QueryDef
    
    tableName = "Projects"
    cParam = "PARAMETERS [par_projectName] Text(255); "
    cSQL = "INSERT INTO " & tableName & "(ProjectName) " & _
           "VALUES (par_projectName);"
           
    On Error GoTo commit_failed
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set cQDf = db.CreateQueryDef("", cSQL)
    
    With cQDf
    .Parameters("par_projectName") = strProjectName
    .Execute dbFailOnError
    .Close
    End With
    addNewProject = True: Exit Function
    
commit_failed:
    addNewProject = False
    
End Function
```

I make this function returns boolean value (True/False) just as confirmation if committing transaction into the db is success or fail.

Then you can call this function from any module (form/standard module):

```
Private Sub cmdSaveInput_Click()
    If addNewProject(txtProjectName) = True Then
        MsgBox "Data saved."
    Else
        MsgBox "Saving data failed."
    End If
    
End Sub
```

or from Immediate window (Ctrl+G):

```
?addnewproject("Watsan Facility")
```

Hope it helps.