# No value given for one or more required parameters error (Excel VBA)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I am creating a program which allows a user to extract student grades and other data for the students enrolled in a specified course. At the moment, I am trying to construct the SQL access statement but there appears to be an error that I am havng trouble disecting.

Additionally, it is important to note that the data is coming from 2 tables.

This is what I have so far. I tried adding brakets around the inner join, excluding the order by statement, and using the table names explicitly with the select statement and whatnot. Nothing has worked yet.

```
SQL = "SELECT G.course, G.A1, G.studentID, S.FirstName, S.LastName " _
        & "FROM grades G INNER JOIN students S ON G.studentID = S.studentID " _
        & "WHERE G.course =" & courseCode & " " _
        & "ORDER BY G.studentID"
```

[This is what the database relatonships are if it helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2JxG.png)

Comment: have you a value for coursecode?

Comment: Is courseCode numeric?  If not then you need single quotes around the value.

Comment: courseCode is a string value structured as 2 letters followed by 3 numbers (ex.CP102)

Comment: Then you need quotes

Comment: I would encourage you to read the following [question about parametrizing commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49509615/8597922) - it would be best practice to use that approach instead of concatenation where possible.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you very much, the quotes were indeed the problem

Comment: @VictorK Will do! Thank you for the tip.